# Using iframes to protect the rest of a page from scripts in 3rd party proxied-in div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sandbox

I have taken over a "dashboard" application that displays lots of goodies.

One of the things displayed is a div that is populated by the content of a 3rd party webpage (which auto-refreshes it's own contents).
Unfortunately the javascript in the imported 3rd party webpage affects/refreshes the entire page it sits on.

Is there a way I can display the content of the 3rd party page on my own page, while at the same time sandboxing it to prevent it from accessing/affecting the page it sits on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use iframe element and put the div element into it

Comment: As seen from my question title, that's what I kind-of thought. However I expected there to be more to it. Apparently not.

Comment: if that 3rd party page contains `<script>try{if(top!=self){throw("")}catch(e){top.location.href=location.href}`, this "solution" will break. See my answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since cross-site scripting limitations prevent you from accessing external HTTP resources through Ajax, you have to use (inline) frames.

I am only aware of ONE way to prevent frames from running scripts. Chrome doesn't support this method, though.

```
var untrusted = document.getElementById("iframe-3rd-party");
untrusted.designMode = "On"; //No script can be run from the frame any more.
```

If you've found a method to avoid the cross-site limitations (eg: [CORS, X-Access-Control-Allow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)), strip the script tags and event handlers from the code. :

```
//xmlhttp_responsestring holds the responseText property of the XMLHttpRequest object
xmlhttp_responsestring
     .replace(/<script[^>]*?>\s*\/\/\s*<\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?]]>\s*<\/script\s*>/gi, "")
     .replace(/<script[\S\s]+?<\/script\s*>/gi,"")
     .replace(/ o([nN])/g," &#111;$1").replace(/ O([Nn])/g," &#79;");
```

All script tags, and al event handlers are stripped in this way: all characters which start with a space, followed by "on" are replaced by HTML entities. Text will still be readable, while the event listeners are disabled.

Note that the last code snippet *only* deals with script tags and event handlers. It doesn't deal with external objects, such as Java Applet and frames. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198) for a more advanced sanitise function.