# Javascript: REGEX to change all relative Urls to Absolute

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, proxy, web-scraping

I'm currently creating a Node.js webscraper/proxy, but I'm having trouble parsing relative Urls found in the scripting part of the source, I figured REGEX would do the trick. 
Although it is unknown how I would achieve this.

Is there anyway I can go about this?

Also I'm open to an easier way of doing this, as I'm quite baffle about how other proxies parse websites. I figured that most are just glorified site scrapers that can read a site's source a relay all links/forms back to the proxy.

Comment: I'd use a real parser, not a regex. There are html parsers for node.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Advanced HTML string replacement functions

*Note for OP, because he requested such a function: Change `base_url` to your proxy's basE URL in order to achieve the desired results.*

Two functions will be shown below (the usage guide is contained within the code). Make sure that you don't skip any part of the explanation of this answer to fully understand the function's behaviour.

- `rel_to_abs(urL)` - This function returns absolute URLs. When an absolute URL with a commonly trusted protocol is passed, it will immediately return this URL. Otherwise, an absolute URL is generated from the `base_url` and the function argument. Relative URLs are correctly parsed (`../` ; `./` ; `.` ; `//`).
- `replace_all_rel_by_abs` - This function will parse **all** occurences of URLs which have a significant meaning in HTML, such as CSS `url()`, links and external resources. See the code for a full list of parsed instances. See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198)** for an adjusted implementation to **sanitise HTML strings** from an external source (to embed in the document).
- Test case (at the bottom of the answer): To test the effectiveness of the function, simply paste the bookmarklet at the location's bar.

---

**`rel_to_abs` - *Parsing relative URLs***

```
function rel_to_abs(url){
    /* Only accept commonly trusted protocols:
     * Only data-image URLs are accepted, Exotic flavours (escaped slash,
     * html-entitied characters) are not supported to keep the function fast */
  if(/^(https?|file|ftps?|mailto|javascript|data:image\/[^;]{2,9};):/i.test(url))
         return url; //Url is already absolute

    var base_url = location.href.match(/^(.+)\/?(?:#.+)?$/)[0]+"/";
    if(url.substring(0,2) == "//")
        return location.protocol + url;
    else if(url.charAt(0) == "/")
        return location.protocol + "//" + location.host + url;
    else if(url.substring(0,2) == "./")
        url = "." + url;
    else if(/^\s*$/.test(url))
        return ""; //Empty = Return nothing
    else url = "../" + url;

    url = base_url + url;
    var i=0
    while(/\/\.\.\//.test(url = url.replace(/[^\/]+\/+\.\.\//g,"")));

    /* Escape certain characters to prevent XSS */
    url = url.replace(/\.$/,"").replace(/\/\./g,"").replace(/"/g,"%22")
            .replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/</g,"%3C").replace(/>/g,"%3E");
    return url;
}
```

Cases / examples:

- `http://foo.bar`. Already an absolute URL, thus returned immediately.
- `/doo` Relative to the root: Returns the current root + provided relative URL.
- `./meh` Relative to the current directory.
- `../booh` Relative to the parent directory.

The function converts relative paths to `../`, and performs a search-and-replace (`http://domain/sub/anything-but-a-slash/../me` to `http://domain/sub/me`).

---

**`replace_all_rel_by_abs` - *Convert all relevant occurences of URLs***
URLs inside script instances (`<script>`, event handlers are **not** replaced, because it's near-impossible to create a fast-and-secure filter to parse JavaScript.

This script is served with some comments inside. Regular Expressions are dynamically created, because an individual RE can have a size of **3000** characters. `<meta http-equiv=refresh content=.. >` can be obfuscated in various ways, hence the size of the RE.

```
function replace_all_rel_by_abs(html){
    /*HTML/XML Attribute may not be prefixed by these characters (common 
       attribute chars.  This list is not complete, but will be sufficient
       for this function (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar). */
    var att = "[^-a-z0-9:._]";

    var entityEnd = "(?:;|(?!\\d))";
    var ents = {" ":"(?:\\s|&nbsp;?|&#0*32"+entityEnd+"|&#x0*20"+entityEnd+")",
                "(":"(?:\\(|&#0*40"+entityEnd+"|&#x0*28"+entityEnd+")",
                ")":"(?:\\)|&#0*41"+entityEnd+"|&#x0*29"+entityEnd+")",
                ".":"(?:\\.|&#0*46"+entityEnd+"|&#x0*2e"+entityEnd+")"};
                /* Placeholders to filter obfuscations */
    var charMap = {};
    var s = ents[" "]+"*"; //Short-hand for common use
    var any = "(?:[^>\"']*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'))*?[^>]*";
    /* ^ Important: Must be pre- and postfixed by < and >.
     *   This RE should match anything within a tag!  */

    /*
      @name ae
      @description  Converts a given string in a sequence of the original
                      input and the HTML entity
      @param String string  String to convert
      */
    function ae(string){
        var all_chars_lowercase = string.toLowerCase();
        if(ents[string]) return ents[string];
        var all_chars_uppercase = string.toUpperCase();
        var RE_res = "";
        for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++){
            var char_lowercase = all_chars_lowercase.charAt(i);
            if(charMap[char_lowercase]){
                RE_res += charMap[char_lowercase];
                continue;
            }
            var char_uppercase = all_chars_uppercase.charAt(i);
            var RE_sub = [char_lowercase];
            RE_sub.push("&#0*" + char_lowercase.charCodeAt(0) + entityEnd);
            RE_sub.push("&#x0*" + char_lowercase.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + entityEnd);
            if(char_lowercase != char_uppercase){
                /* Note: RE ignorecase flag has already been activated */
                RE_sub.push("&#0*" + char_uppercase.charCodeAt(0) + entityEnd);   
                RE_sub.push("&#x0*" + char_uppercase.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + entityEnd);
            }
            RE_sub = "(?:" + RE_sub.join("|") + ")";
            RE_res += (charMap[char_lowercase] = RE_sub);
        }
        return(ents[string] = RE_res);
    }

    /*
      @name by
      @description  2nd argument for replace().
      */
    function by(match, group1, group2, group3){
        /* Note that this function can also be used to remove links:
         * return group1 + "javascript://" + group3; */
        return group1 + rel_to_abs(group2) + group3;
    }
    /*
      @name by2
      @description  2nd argument for replace(). Parses relevant HTML entities
      */
    var slashRE = new RegExp(ae("/"), 'g');
    var dotRE = new RegExp(ae("."), 'g');
    function by2(match, group1, group2, group3){
        /*Note that this function can also be used to remove links:
         * return group1 + "javascript://" + group3; */
        group2 = group2.replace(slashRE, "/").replace(dotRE, ".");
        return group1 + rel_to_abs(group2) + group3;
    }
    /*
      @name cr
      @description            Selects a HTML element and performs a
                                search-and-replace on attributes
      @param String selector  HTML substring to match
      @param String attribute RegExp-escaped; HTML element attribute to match
      @param String marker    Optional RegExp-escaped; marks the prefix
      @param String delimiter Optional RegExp escaped; non-quote delimiters
      @param String end       Optional RegExp-escaped; forces the match to end
                              before an occurence of <end>
     */
    function cr(selector, attribute, marker, delimiter, end){
        if(typeof selector == "string") selector = new RegExp(selector, "gi");
        attribute = att + attribute;
        marker = typeof marker == "string" ? marker : "\\s*=\\s*";
        delimiter = typeof delimiter == "string" ? delimiter : "";
        end = typeof end == "string" ? "?)("+end : ")(";
        var re1 = new RegExp('('+attribute+marker+'")([^"'+delimiter+']+'+end+')', 'gi');
        var re2 = new RegExp("("+attribute+marker+"')([^'"+delimiter+"]+"+end+")", 'gi');
        var re3 = new RegExp('('+attribute+marker+')([^"\'][^\\s>'+delimiter+']*'+end+')', 'gi');
        html = html.replace(selector, function(match){
            return match.replace(re1, by).replace(re2, by).replace(re3, by);
        });
    }
    /* 
      @name cri
      @description            Selects an attribute of a HTML element, and
                                performs a search-and-replace on certain values
      @param String selector  HTML element to match
      @param String attribute RegExp-escaped; HTML element attribute to match
      @param String front     RegExp-escaped; attribute value, prefix to match
      @param String flags     Optional RegExp flags, default "gi"
      @param String delimiter Optional RegExp-escaped; non-quote delimiters
      @param String end       Optional RegExp-escaped; forces the match to end
                                before an occurence of <end>
     */
    function cri(selector, attribute, front, flags, delimiter, end){
        if(typeof selector == "string") selector = new RegExp(selector, "gi");
        attribute = att + attribute;
        flags = typeof flags == "string" ? flags : "gi";
        var re1 = new RegExp('('+attribute+'\\s*=\\s*")([^"]*)', 'gi');
        var re2 = new RegExp("("+attribute+"\\s*=\\s*')([^']+)", 'gi');
        var at1 = new RegExp('('+front+')([^"]+)(")', flags);
        var at2 = new RegExp("("+front+")([^']+)(')", flags);
        if(typeof delimiter == "string"){
            end = typeof end == "string" ? end : "";
            var at3 = new RegExp("("+front+")([^\"'][^"+delimiter+"]*" + (end?"?)("+end+")":")()"), flags);
            var handleAttr = function(match, g1, g2){return g1+g2.replace(at1, by2).replace(at2, by2).replace(at3, by2)};
        } else {
            var handleAttr = function(match, g1, g2){return g1+g2.replace(at1, by2).replace(at2, by2)};
    }
        html = html.replace(selector, function(match){
             return match.replace(re1, handleAttr).replace(re2, handleAttr);
        });
    }

    /* <meta http-equiv=refresh content="  ; url= " > */
    cri("<meta"+any+att+"http-equiv\\s*=\\s*(?:\""+ae("refresh")+"\""+any+">|'"+ae("refresh")+"'"+any+">|"+ae("refresh")+"(?:"+ae(" ")+any+">|>))", "content", ae("url")+s+ae("=")+s, "i");

    cr("<"+any+att+"href\\s*="+any+">", "href"); /* Linked elements */
    cr("<"+any+att+"src\\s*="+any+">", "src"); /* Embedded elements */

    cr("<object"+any+att+"data\\s*="+any+">", "data"); /* <object data= > */
    cr("<applet"+any+att+"codebase\\s*="+any+">", "codebase"); /* <applet codebase= > */

    /* <param name=movie value= >*/
    cr("<param"+any+att+"name\\s*=\\s*(?:\""+ae("movie")+"\""+any+">|'"+ae("movie")+"'"+any+">|"+ae("movie")+"(?:"+ae(" ")+any+">|>))", "value");

    cr(/<style[^>]*>(?:[^"']*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*?[^'"]*(?:<\/style|$)/gi, "url", "\\s*\\(\\s*", "", "\\s*\\)"); /* <style> */
    cri("<"+any+att+"style\\s*="+any+">", "style", ae("url")+s+ae("(")+s, 0, s+ae(")"), ae(")")); /*< style=" url(...) " > */
    return html;
}
```

A short summary of the private functions:

- `rel_to_abs(url)` - Converts relative / unknown URLs to absolute URLs
- `replace_all_rel_by_abs(html)` - Replaces all relevant occurences of URLs within a string of HTML by absolute URLs.

  1. `ae` - **A**ny **E**ntity - Returns a RE-pattern to deal with HTML entities.
  2. `by` - replace **by** - This short function request the actual url replace (`rel_to_abs`). This function may be called hundreds, if not thousand times. Be careful to not add a slow algorithm to this function (customisation).
  3. `cr` - **C**reate **R**eplace - Creates and executes a search-and-replace.
     Example: `href="..."` (within any HTML tag).
  4. `cri` - **C**reate **R**eplace **I**nline - Creates and executes a search-and-replace.
     Example: `url(..)` within the all `style` attribute within HTML tags.

#### Test case

Open any page, and paste the following bookmarklet in the location bar:

```
javascript:void(function(){var s=document.createElement("script");s.src="http://rob.lekensteyn.nl/rel_to_abs.js";document.body.appendChild(s)})();
```

The injected code contains the two functions, as defined above, plus the test case, shown below. **Note**: The test case does **not** modify the HTML of the page, but shows the parsed results in a textarea (optionally).

```
var t=(new Date).getTime();
  var result = replace_all_rel_by_abs(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
  if(confirm((new Date).getTime()-t+" milliseconds to execute\n\nPut results in new textarea?")){
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.style.cssText = "position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:99%"
    txt.ondblclick = function(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this)}
    txt.value = result;
    document.body.appendChild(txt);
}
```

See also:

- [Answer: Parsing and sanitising HTML strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198)

Comment: Thanks, do you know any way I can match all the relative urls in the script though?

Comment: Include my function in your code, and call `rel_to_abs` whenever you want to get an absolute URL from a possibly relative URL, eg: `var some_url = ".././callback/xhr.php";rel_to_abs(some_url)`;

Comment: Yes I understand. But I meant, how would I be able to scan through the site I'm proxying in order to find these urls?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Going to finish it later, because I really have to go.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will be very helpful, looking forward to the update!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this extensive piece of code, great help! I noticed that the code included in the answer is not in sync (anymore ?) with the js file loaded from http://rob.lekensteyn.nl/rel_to_abs.js. Here is my code adapted for Node.js

Comment: ... ran out of time :)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8561342/d3/reltoabslink.js

Comment: Are these functions in github or npm repo?

Comment: @Alex No. And I wouldn't use them. 4 years ago I was happily writing complicated regexes to parse URLs, but now I recommend to use dedicated URL parsers or DOM parsers (all modern browsers have these capabilities these days). If you're using Node.js, use the `url` module. If you use browsers, use the [`URL` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), `document.createElement('a')` or any other url library.

Comment: @RobW What about a modern `replace_all_rel_by_abs ` function for finding all the relative URLs in an HTML document?  Which parser do you recommend? Would all options require loading the HTML into DOM first?  I like that your function does a search/replace on text HTML document.

Comment: @Alex If the result is going to be shown as a HTML page, simply put a `<base>` tag in the HTML and then you don't need to parse the page at all (and it will also work for external resources). Otherwise you can create a document using the [`DOMParser` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and then traverse the document tree and replace everything you care about (e.g. text nodes, HTML attributes, style sheets, ...).

Comment: Unfortunately, on practice never converted all links in web-pages for me. [**Example 1**](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/planetarium_demo.html) — not converted links like `data-ptr-pattern="planetarium/texture-saturn.jpg"`, [**Example 2**](http://javier.xyz/react-textgradient/) — in output absent half of source, [**Example 3**](https://codyhouse.co/demo/animated-headlines/) — bookmarklet not run. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob W following you comment I wrote a base injector function, see "answer" below

Comment: @RobW The regex fails when an image is a base64 type. I had to update it to 

```if (/^((https?|file|ftps?|mailto|javascript):|(data:image\/[^;]{2,9};))/i.test(url))```

Comment: @RobW What are some ways the `meta http-equiv` can be obfuscated? I was thinking of writing a modern version of this that uses an actual DOM parsing library.

Answer (score 2):

A reliable way to convert urls from relative to absolute is to use the built-in [`url` module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to).

Example:

```
var url = require('url');
url.resolve("http://www.example.org/foo/bar/", "../baz/qux.html");

>> gives 'http://www.example.org/foo/baz/qux.html'
```

Comment: where does "require" come from?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz: the question was about a Node.js application. `require()` is the Node.js equivalent of C `#include <...>`. (Well, not exactly.) So, my answer cannot be used when writing JS code to run in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Rob W answer "Advanced HTML string replacement functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544757/1983903) in current thread plus some code re-factoring from me to make JSLint happy.

I should post it as answer's comment but I don't have enough reputation points.

```js
/*jslint browser: true */
/*jslint regexp: true */
/*jslint unparam: true*/
/*jshint strict: false */

/**
 * convertRelToAbsUrl
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544757/1983903
 * 
 * @param  {String} url
 * @return {String} updated url
 */
function convertRelToAbsUrl(url) {
    var baseUrl = null;

    if (/^(https?|file|ftps?|mailto|javascript|data:image\/[^;]{2,9};):/i.test(url)) {
        return url; // url is already absolute
    }

    baseUrl = location.href.match(/^(.+)\/?(?:#.+)?$/)[0] + '/';

    if (url.substring(0, 2) === '//') {
        return location.protocol + url;
    }
    if (url.charAt(0) === '/') {
        return location.protocol + '//' + location.host + url;
    }
    if (url.substring(0, 2) === './') {
        url = '.' + url;
    } else if (/^\s*$/.test(url)) {
        return ''; // empty = return nothing
    }

    url = baseUrl + '../' + url;

    while (/\/\.\.\//.test(url)) {
        url = url.replace(/[^\/]+\/+\.\.\//g, '');
    }

    url = url.replace(/\.$/, '').replace(/\/\./g, '').replace(/"/g, '%22')
            .replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/</g, '%3C').replace(/>/g, '%3E');

    return url;
}

/**
 * convertAllRelativeToAbsoluteUrls
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544757/1983903
 * 
 * @param  {String} html
 * @return {String} updated html
 */
function convertAllRelativeToAbsoluteUrls(html) {
    var me = this,
        att = '[^-a-z0-9:._]',
        entityEnd = '(?:;|(?!\\d))',
        ents = {
            ' ' : '(?:\\s|&nbsp;?|&#0*32' + entityEnd + '|&#x0*20' + entityEnd + ')',
            '(' : '(?:\\(|&#0*40' + entityEnd + '|&#x0*28' + entityEnd + ')',
            ')' : '(?:\\)|&#0*41' + entityEnd + '|&#x0*29' + entityEnd + ')',
            '.' : '(?:\\.|&#0*46' + entityEnd + '|&#x0*2e' + entityEnd + ')'
        },
        charMap = {},
        s = ents[' '] + '*', // short-hand for common use
        any = '(?:[^>\"\']*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\'))*?[^>]*',
        slashRE = null,
        dotRE = null;

    function ae(string) {
        var allCharsLowerCase = string.toLowerCase(),
            allCharsUpperCase = string.toUpperCase(),
            reRes = '',
            charLowerCase = null,
            charUpperCase = null,
            reSub = null,
            i = null;

        if (ents[string]) {
            return ents[string];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
            charLowerCase = allCharsLowerCase.charAt(i);
            if (charMap[charLowerCase]) {
                reRes += charMap[charLowerCase];
                continue;
            }
            charUpperCase = allCharsUpperCase.charAt(i);
            reSub = [charLowerCase];
            reSub.push('&#0*' + charLowerCase.charCodeAt(0) + entityEnd);
            reSub.push('&#x0*' + charLowerCase.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + entityEnd);

            if (charLowerCase !== charUpperCase) {
                reSub.push('&#0*' + charUpperCase.charCodeAt(0) + entityEnd);
                reSub.push('&#x0*' + charUpperCase.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + entityEnd);
            }
            reSub = '(?:' + reSub.join('|') + ')';
            reRes += (charMap[charLowerCase] = reSub);
        }
        return (ents[string] = reRes);
    }

    function by(match, group1, group2, group3) {
        return group1 + me.convertRelToAbsUrl(group2) + group3;
    }

    slashRE = new RegExp(ae('/'), 'g');
    dotRE = new RegExp(ae('.'), 'g');

    function by2(match, group1, group2, group3) {
        group2 = group2.replace(slashRE, '/').replace(dotRE, '.');
        return group1 + me.convertRelToAbsUrl(group2) + group3;
    }

    function cr(selector, attribute, marker, delimiter, end) {
        var re1 = null,
            re2 = null,
            re3 = null;

        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            selector = new RegExp(selector, 'gi');
        }

        attribute = att + attribute;
        marker = typeof marker === 'string' ? marker : '\\s*=\\s*';
        delimiter = typeof delimiter === 'string' ? delimiter : '';
        end = typeof end === 'string' ? '?)(' + end : ')(';

        re1 = new RegExp('(' + attribute + marker + '")([^"' + delimiter + ']+' + end + ')', 'gi');
        re2 = new RegExp('(' + attribute + marker + '\')([^\'' + delimiter + ']+' + end + ')', 'gi');
        re3 = new RegExp('(' + attribute + marker + ')([^"\'][^\\s>' + delimiter + ']*' + end + ')', 'gi');

        html = html.replace(selector, function (match) {
            return match.replace(re1, by).replace(re2, by).replace(re3, by);
        });
    }

    function cri(selector, attribute, front, flags, delimiter, end) {
        var re1 = null,
            re2 = null,
            at1 = null,
            at2 = null,
            at3 = null,
            handleAttr = null;

        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            selector = new RegExp(selector, 'gi');
        }

        attribute = att + attribute;
        flags = typeof flags === 'string' ? flags : 'gi';
        re1 = new RegExp('(' + attribute + '\\s*=\\s*")([^"]*)', 'gi');
        re2 = new RegExp("(" + attribute + "\\s*=\\s*')([^']+)", 'gi');
        at1 = new RegExp('(' + front + ')([^"]+)(")', flags);
        at2 = new RegExp("(" + front + ")([^']+)(')", flags);

        if (typeof delimiter === 'string') {
            end = typeof end === 'string' ? end : '';
            at3 = new RegExp('(' + front + ')([^\"\'][^' + delimiter + ']*' + (end ? '?)(' + end + ')' : ')()'), flags);
            handleAttr = function (match, g1, g2) {
                return g1 + g2.replace(at1, by2).replace(at2, by2).replace(at3, by2);
            };
        } else {
            handleAttr = function (match, g1, g2) {
                return g1 + g2.replace(at1, by2).replace(at2, by2);
            };
        }
        html = html.replace(selector, function (match) {
            return match.replace(re1, handleAttr).replace(re2, handleAttr);
        });
    }

    cri('<meta' + any + att + 'http-equiv\\s*=\\s*(?:\"' + ae('refresh')
        + '\"' + any + '>|\'' + ae('refresh') + '\'' + any + '>|' + ae('refresh')
        + '(?:' + ae(' ') + any + '>|>))', 'content', ae('url') + s + ae('=') + s, 'i');

    cr('<' + any + att + 'href\\s*=' + any + '>', 'href'); /* Linked elements */
    cr('<' + any + att + 'src\\s*=' + any + '>', 'src'); /* Embedded elements */

    cr('<object' + any + att + 'data\\s*=' + any + '>', 'data'); /* <object data= > */
    cr('<applet' + any + att + 'codebase\\s*=' + any + '>', 'codebase'); /* <applet codebase= > */

    /* <param name=movie value= >*/
    cr('<param' + any + att + 'name\\s*=\\s*(?:\"' + ae('movie') + '\"' + any + '>|\''
        + ae('movie') + '\'' + any + '>|' + ae('movie') + '(?:' + ae(' ') + any + '>|>))', 'value');

    cr(/<style[^>]*>(?:[^"']*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*?[^'"]*(?:<\/style|$)/gi,
        'url', '\\s*\\(\\s*', '', '\\s*\\)'); /* <style> */
    cri('<' + any + att + 'style\\s*=' + any + '>', 'style',
        ae('url') + s + ae('(') + s, 0, s + ae(')'), ae(')')); /*< style=" url(...) " > */

    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regex to find all non-absolute URLs, you can then just prefix them with the current URL and that should be it.

The URLs you need to fix would be ones which don't start either with a `/` or `http(s)://` (or other protocol markers, if you care about them)

As an example, let's say you're scraping `http://www.example.com/`. If you encounter a relative URL, let's say `foo/bar`, you would simply prefix the URL being scraped to it like so: `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`

For a regex to scrape the URLs from the page, there are probably plenty of good ones available if you google a bit so I'm not going to start inventing a poor one here :)

Comment: @rob-w If base url like
" http://www.example.org/user/account/ " (last / in href) then it will be not convert to absolute.
Ex.:
    <a href="edit.html">Edit</a>
    It's give : http://www.example.org/user/edit.html
    It should be
   http://www.example.org/user/account/edit.html

Answer (score 0):

From a comment by Rob W above about the base tag I wrote an injection function:

```
function injectBase(html, base) {
  // Remove any <base> elements inside <head>     
  html = html.replace(/(<[^>/]*head[^>]*>)[\s\S]*?(<[^>/]*base[^>]*>)[\s\S]*?(<[^>]*head[^>]*>)/img, "$1 $3");

  // Add <base> just before </head>  
  html = html.replace(/(<[^>/]*head[^>]*>[\s\S]*?)(<[^>]*head[^>]*>)/img, "$1 " + base + " $2");  
  return(html);
}
```