# Regex to change <img> relative URLs to absolute

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to look inside a string of HTML and change all `<img>` tags where the `src` attribute is a relative address, to an absolute URL. So this:

```
<img src="puppies.jpg">
```

needs to become:

```
<img src="http://sitename.com/path/puppies.jpg">
```

while ignoring `<img>` tags whose `src` attribute is already absolute.

I'm using PHP and assume that I'll need to run this through `preg_replace()`. Help! And Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: REGEX to change all relative Urls to Absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544550/javascript-regex-to-change-all-relative-urls-to-absolute)

Comment: That's for JavaScript, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Consider using DomDocument class instead of preg for doing HTML stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *not* a job for a regular expression.  It's a job for an XML/DOM parser.

I'd give DOMDocument a shot.

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$imgs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgs as $img){
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    if(strpos($src, 'http://sitename.com/path/') !== 0){
        $img->setAttribute('src', "http://sitename.com/path/$src");
    }
}

$html = $DOM->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I upvoted, but it also needs a check for `src` attributes which are already absolute, per the OP.

Comment: @Mathletics: Ah yes, didn't notice that, I can add that :-P

Comment: @Jack: Good idea, changed :-P

Comment: Yay! That does it! Question: the HTML that gets returned automatically gets a <doctype>, <html>, <body>, etc... tags. Is there any way to turn that off? All I want is what I gave it to start... just with the find-and-replace part done. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> This is not a job for a regular expression. It's a job for an XML/DOM
>   parser.

Nope it's not. If you just want to add a prefix to each src attribute, it's best to use simple string functions and don't even think about xml, regex or dom parsing…

```
$str = str_replace('<img src="', '<img src="http://prefix', $str);
```

You can clean up wrong links (already absolute ones) afterwards

```
$str = str_replace('<img src="http://prefixhttp://', '<img src="http://', $str);
```

Do not blow up your code with regexp/dom if you can avoid it.

Comment: What would happen happen if my HTML was `<img class='animals' src='puppies.jpg' />`?

Comment: @Rocket sorry, but he said his HTML is `<img src="puppies.jpg">`

Comment: wrong links can easily be fixed: 

`str_replace('prefixprefix', 'prefix', $str)`

`str_replace('http://prefix/http://', 'http://', $str)`

don't blow up your code with regex/dom if you do not have to…

Comment: @semu, I'm totally with you on this one. For *this* instance (and mine) there's no reason to add all kinds of unnecessary overhead when a simple solution exist... albeit not the most graceful, it definitely gets the job done.