# Glype Proxy preg replace source

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Pleas help me with this [Glype proxy](https://github.com/vincentclee/glype) source code. I want to make a new proxy script but I have some big issue.
When I access the website I get the styles and javascript src like this:

```
src="/images/"
```

And I want to change it with preg_replace or str_replace with src="http://example.com/images/"

I have tried this options:

```
$input = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $input);
    $input = preg_replace("/\r|\n/", "", $input);
    $input = str_replace('href="/images/', 'href="http://example.com/images/', $input);
```

but nothing change is still show me the website without styles.

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you help me with some examples? Because I am beginner and I cannot solve the issue!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389153/regex-to-change-img-relative-urls-to-absolute