# What is the best way to get all image urls from an external web page in node.js

Tags: node.js

From node, I'd like to get all image urls (`src` attribute from `img` tags) from an external web page.

I started by considering phantonjs, but didn't like that it's not really integrated into node (i.e. it runs in an external process).

Next, I tried to use the request module and cheerio. This works great, except I have to deal with relative image urls. E.g.

```
<img src='http//example.com/i.jpg'>
<img src='/i.jpg'>
<img src='i.jpg'>
<img src='../images/i.jpg'>
```

I can deal with that, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way?

Comment: I imagine request + cheerio is probably the easiest way. You could also use jquery + js-dom instead

Comment: Could these relative-to-absolute methods help you out?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544550/javascript-regex-to-change-all-relative-urls-to-absolute

Comment: Looks like node's [url](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) module may do the trick here.

Comment: simple thing you can try the Headless browser and with Nodejs try Puppeteer

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using the `request` node module along with `cheerio` and `url`. Here's what I ended up doing (please note, this is mvp code, not production quality):

```
app.get('/scrape-images', function(req, res) {
  request(req.query.url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      var reqUrl = url.parse(req.query.url);

      res.send($('img').map(function(i, e) {
        var srcUrl = url.parse($(e).attr('src'));

        if (!srcUrl.host) {
          return url.resolve(reqUrl, srcUrl);
        } else {
          return url.format(srcUrl);
        }
      }));
    }
  });
});
```