# How to avoid Cross-Origin Read Blocking(CORB) in a chrome web extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-origin-read-blocking

I wrote a [chrome web extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tnt/imheopooeklpkepinokgifdbfemhcoii?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) to avoid CORS limitation when developing my own web apps. The extension is a developers' tool and used to proxy the request from the source url to the dest url.

The extension core code like this, thus developers can develop their pages on my 
 site and request to their server side without CORS limitation:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(details => {
  let redirectUrl = '';
  //...
  redirectUrl = details.url.replace(TNT.validRules[i].source, TNT.validRules[i].dest);
 return {redirectUrl}
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking']);


chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
  details.responseHeaders.map(item => {
    if (item.name.toLowerCase() == 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.toLowerCase()) {
      item.value = '*'
    }
  })
  return {responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

But the latest Chrome 72 cannot proxy the request. And the console errors are:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://xxxxxxx.com/abc.json?siteId=69
>   with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Comment: Perform the request in your background page and send the results to your content script via messaging.

Comment: Indeed I add an eventListener onHeadersReceived and set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'='*' in the background.js. The extension works well before chrome 72. But it does not work now.

Comment: Just stumbled upon the [official explainer](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches#TOC-2.-Avoid-Cross-Origin-Fetches-in-Content-Scripts) that demonstrates what I said above.

Comment: Thanks.That's the reason why the extension not work. I still need to figure out how to solve the problem.Do not know how many costs it will take :(

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry for my poor english. Do the codes explain my question clearly?

Comment: I think this is the same problem with mine. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933893

Comment: I still don't get why you need such a convoluted approach instead of making the requests in the background script, but if the issue you've linked is indeed relevant, all you need is to add 'extraHeaders' as explained in the comments there and in the documentation.

Comment: The extension is a develop tool to enable CORS for testing purposes. I will have a try as the comments said. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: This sudden CORB restriction for content scripts is asinine, especially since there was no communication sent out to developers to notify of this upcoming deprecation. There are surely PLENTY of background script extensions that need to make API calls to work properly. And what about when we are using third party components that make api calls, which we do not have control over?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this issue filed by co-founder at Moesif.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933893

Based on his discussion with Chronium engineers, basically, you should added `extraHeaders`
into extra options for when adding listeners, which will pull this trigger closer to the network and inject the headers before CORB gets triggered.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
  const responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders.map(item => {
    if (item.name.toLowerCase() === 'access-control-allow-origin') {
      item.value = '*'
    }
  })
  return { responseHeaders };
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders', 'extraHeaders'])
```

Btw, a little self promotion here. Why don't you just use our CORS tool,

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en

It is already the most feature complete CORS tool.

Comment: Using Chrome 72.0.3626.121 I get past the CORS extension, but the request dies with:
core.js:15723 ERROR TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a function
    at ApiService.push../src/app/services/api.service.ts.ApiService.logError (api.service.ts:49)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (api.service.ts:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
,,,

Comment: I am using the cors tool, and this solved it for me. Thanks Derrick

Comment: @derrick is 'blocking' option necessary in this example?

Comment: Thanks for saving my head from banging it to wall. Only solution that worked for me is the Moesif CORS tool.

Answer (score 13):

I've found answer in the google docs:

**Avoid Cross-Origin Fetches in Content Scripts**

*Old content script, making a cross-origin fetch:*

```js
var itemId = 12345;
var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
         encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => parsePrice(text))
  .then(price => ...)
  .catch(error => ...)
```

*New content script, asking its background page to fetch the data instead:*

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {contentScriptQuery: "queryPrice", itemId: 12345},
    price => ...);
```

*New extension background page, fetching from a known URL and relaying data:*

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.contentScriptQuery == "queryPrice") {
      var url = "https://another-site.com/price-query?itemId=" +
              encodeURIComponent(request.itemId);
      fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => parsePrice(text))
          .then(price => sendResponse(price))
          .catch(error => ...)
      return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
  });
```

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

Comment: Main answer should be updated with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to use some browser-specific API? What is this, IE all over again? :-|

Comment: I was trying to call the Mixpanel API to send data and [Edge was blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/tracking-prevention) the requests. Although I was able to get it to work by changed the setting in edge, this is the correct way to implement it. This helped me, thank you.