# Response is coming as null after making HTTP get call followed by CORB warning in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, ionic4

Not able to figure out why the response is coming as `null`.

When tested with mock data, it works perfectly fine but when I'm trying to hit our API which is hosted in AWS EC2, the response comes as `null` and the error message comes in the console as follows

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://example.com/search/api?limit=10&offset=10 with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

However, I verified in the browser's Network tab, It shows `200 OK`. Also, I verified this API call with Postman client and the data is being shown.

I tried various ways of disabling the web security option in Chrome browser but no luck. I also have CORS extension in my Chrome browser.

Could anyone please guide what I'm doing wrong here.

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

  searchUrl = 'http://example.com/search/api?limit=10&offset=10'
  mockDataUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getMockData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.mockDataUrl);
  }

  getSearchData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.searchUrl);
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchService.getSearchData().subscribe(
      (response) => { console.log(response); }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For resolving CORS, you need to allow your origin in on the server. check `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the server or you can check this in response headers of inflight call.

Comment: I'm able to get the data if I try to hit the API using Postman or any browser. The problem persists when I'm trying to hit that API through my Ionic App. @AnandG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835157/7004388) that worked for me.

Once I installed this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en) and enabled it, I was able to see the response.