# Is there something like simple_html_dom.php for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building an iPhone app using Appcelerator Titanium, and I need to convert a HTML string (which may contain invalid HTML like missing tags, not my fault) to a DOM object. In this DOM element I need to find a specific `<div>`, and put the contents of this `<div>` in a WebView.

Anyway, I am looking for something like the [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) script, which is for PHP, to search through the DOM for this `<div>`. I'd like the script to scan the (invalid) HTML string, and get the innerHTML of the `<div>`.

How can I best do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

The code below is the basic string-to-DOM convertor. See the linked answer for a detailed explanation.

```
function string2dom(html, callback){    
    /* Create an IFrame */
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(html);
    doc.close();

    function destroy(){
        iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    }
    if(callback) callback(doc, destroy);
    else return {"doc": doc, "destroy": destroy};
}
```

This code snippet does not sanitise the HTML. Scripts will be executed, external sources will be loaded. The explanation of the code, and HTML sanitiser can be found at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198)**

Usage (examples), Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JFSKe/:

```
string2dom("<html><head><title>Test</title></head></html>", function(doc, destroy){
    alert(doc.title); /* Alert: "Test" */
    destroy();
});

var test = string2dom("<div id='secret'></div>");
alert(test.doc.getElementById("secret").tagName); /* Alert: "DIV" */
test.destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, Titanium doesn't recognise the `document` property since it doesn't exist. Is it possible to convert the string to DOM in another way?

Comment: Titanium doesn't provide any DOM methods. If your desired document fragment is well-structured, using a RegExp wouldn't hurt. Otherwise, I recommend to take a look at the Appcelerator Q&A: http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/tag/dom