# How to replace all BUT the first occurrence of a pattern in string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

quick question: my pattern is an svg string and it looks like `l 5 0 l 0 10 l -5 0 l 0 -10` To do some unittest comparison against a reference I need to ditch all but the first `l` I know i can ditch them all and put an 'l' upfront, or I can use substrings. But I'm wondering is there a javascript regexp idiom for this?

Comment: Is the first l always at the start of the string?

Comment: i know you said you don't want this, but substring up to the first space seems like the easiest to read and maintain.

Comment: @Mark yes for this usecase, it is even ' l', but that also works with the negative lookahead.

Comment: @Randy yes I know, but I wanted to deepen my knowledge on regexps. Your point about readability and maintainability is something to consider. I'll start with commenting.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try a negative lookahead, avoiding the start of the string:

```
/(?!^)l/g
```

See if online: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVsPS/)

Comment: I'm trying to modify this to work for the first '-' character that appears, and I'm having a very difficult time of it :(. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would I use this with a variable?

Comment: @GrantRobertSmith I know this is way late, but I provided an answer that covers what I think you're looking for.

Comment: This only works if the first `l` is also at the start of the string.

Answer (score 8):

There's no JS RegExp to replace everything-but-the-first-pattern-match. You can, however, implement this behaviour by passing a function as a second argument to the `replace`method.

```
var regexp = /(foo bar )(red)/g; //Example
var string = "somethingfoo bar red  foo bar red red pink   foo bar red red";
var first = true;

//The arguments of the function are similar to $0 $1 $2 $3 etc
var fn_replaceBy = function(match, group1, group2){ //group in accordance with RE
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        return match;
    }
    // Else, deal with RegExp, for example:
    return group1 + group2.toUpperCase();
}
string = string.replace(regexp, fn_replaceBy);
//equals string = "something foo bar red  foo bar RED red pink   foo bar RED red"
```

The function (`fn_replaceBy`) is executed for each match. At the first match, the function immediately returns with the matched string (nothing happens), and a flag is set.
Every other match will be replaced according to the logic as described in the function: Normally, you use `$0 $1 $2`, et cetera, to refer back to groups. In `fn_replaceBy`, the function arguments equal these: First argument = `$0`, second argument = `$1`, et cetera.

The matched substring will be replaced by the return value of function `fn_replaceBy`. Using a function as a second parameter for `replace` allows very powerful applcations, such as an [intelligent HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer#7539198).

See also: [MDN: String.replace > Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: I wasn't convinced the "intelligent HTML parser" wasn't going to link to the "parse HTML using regex" answer, haha. But very nice answer, this was just what I needed. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not the prettiest solution, but you could replace the first occurrence with something arbitrary (like a placeholder) and chain replacements to fulfill the rest of the logic:

```
'-98324792u4234jkdfhk.sj.dh-f01' // construct valid float
    .replace(/[^\d\.-]/g, '') // first, remove all characters that aren't common
    .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '') // replace negative characters that aren't in beginning
    .replace('.', '%FD%') // replace first occurrence of decimal point (placeholder)
    .replace(/\./g, '') // now replace all but first occurrence (refer to above)
    .replace(/%FD%(0+)?$/, '') // remove placeholder if not necessary at end of string
    .replace('%FD%', '.') // otherwise, replace placeholder with period
```

Produces:

`-983247924234.01`

This merely expands on the accepted answer for anyone looking for an example that can't depend on the first match/occurrence being the first character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
 "l 5 0 l 0 10 l -5 0 l 0 -10".replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+l/g, '')
```

makes sure the first `'l'` is not preceded by space and removes any space followed by an `'l'`.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

`"l 5 0 l 0 10 l -5 0 l 0 -10".replace(/[^^]l/g, '')`

Comment: Although this does work in this case, doesn't `^` represent the literal character in a character class?

Comment: `[^^]` matches any character besides `'^'`.  It does not match zero-characters at any point other than the start of input as you require.  `(!/[^^]/.test('^') && /[^^]/.test('x')) === true`

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution at https://www.regextester.com/99881, using a lookbehind pattern:

`/(?<=(.*l.*))l/g`

Or more generally

`/(?<=(.*MYSTRING.*))MYSTRING/g`

where `MYSTRING` is something that you want to remove.

(This may also be a useful string for removing all but the first occurrence of "Re:" in an email subject string, by the way.)

Comment: Variable length lookbehind is not supported by all regex flavor. In Javascript, lookbehind is not supported by all browsers.