# Remove all html tags from string by list, except the first one

Tags: javascript

I have string of html tags and a list of forbidden tags:
Any tag that is found in forbiddenTags should be removed from str, except the first one.

**Maybe it can be done by one loop of the string**

I tried the next thing:

```
var forbiddenTags = ["div", "city"];

var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
            '<ADDUMP>' +
            '    <HEADER>' +
            '        <div></div>' +
            '        <div>Help Wanted Line</div>' +
            '    </HEADER>' +
            '    <ADINFO>' +
            '        <CUSTOMER>' +
            '            <CITY></CITY>' +
            '            <Div></DIV>' +
            '            <STATE></STATE>' +
            '       </CUSTOMER>' +
            '   </ADINFO>' +
            '</ADDUMP>' +
            '</xml>';

var arrayLength = forbiddenTags.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    // remove all forbiddenTags (upper and lower case)
    var re = new RegExp("</? *" + forbiddenTags[i] + "[^>]*>","gi");
    str = str.replace(re, "");
}

console.log(str);
```

Unfortunately, there are two problems:

1) It removes also the first tag of the string that is found in forbiddenTags.

2) It doesn't remove the content of the tags.

example:

```
<div>hi</div>
<div>how</div>
<div></div>
```

should be:

```
<div>hi</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3469/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the content of the tag as well as the tag itself, you need to change your regex to look for both the opening and closing tag at the same time. Currently, it only checks for one or the other, which is why the tag content is being left.

This regex looks for an opening tag (and any associated attributes) the matching closing tag, and any intervening text:

```
new RegExp("<(" + forbiddenTags[i] + ")[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>", "gi")
```

Your other issue (not wanting to remove the first match) can be solved by [passing an anonymous function as a parameter to `str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). In that function, make use of a counter variable to determine when to remove a match.

To do that, you'll need to add a counter variable somewhere. If you want to leave the first match of *each type of forbidden tag*, put it inside your `for` loop. If you only want to keep the first forbidden tag found overall, initialize it outside your `for` loop (it's unclear which you want from your question). Then replace `str = str.replace(re, "");` with this:

```
str = str.replace(re, function(matchedText){
    if (++counter>1){
        return "";
    } else {
        return matchedText;
    }
});
```

This function runs against every match. If it's the first match, it simply returns that match (in effect, leaving it alone). Otherwise, it removes it.

Now, all together this makes your loop look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenTags.length; i++) {
    var counter=0
    var re = new RegExp("<(" + forbiddenTags[i] + ")[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>", "gi");
    str = str.replace(re, function(matchedText){
        if (++counter>1){
            return "";
        } else {
            return matchedText;
        }
    });
}
```

---

If using jQuery is an option, you can make things look a bit cleaner (namely, removing that obnoxious regex) using the function found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110097/919057):

```
var removeElements = function(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector+":not(:first)").remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}

for (var i = 0; i < forbiddenTags.length; i++) {
    str = removeElements(str, forbiddenTags[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.match` to get all matches and discard all except for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer by Rob W on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959975/how-to-replace-all-but-the-first-occurence-of-a-pattern-in-string) is what you are looking for.
All you need to change is the `first = true` to `first = {}` and check

```
if (!first[tag]) {
    first[tag] = true;
} else {
    return '';
}
```