# Ho get all occurrency except the first

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose to have this string: test

and I want to delete all occurences of test in a example string.

Suppose to have this string:

```
@33<.ùasdasd3123test#21871,testasdfxtestsdfgùà+è
```

The string can be composed in all way is not only letters or point, my regex is:

```
new Regex(/\test/g);
```

but this regex delete all occurrency about the world text in the string.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: `\t` is changed to the tab character in a regex. Get rid of the `\\` and try again.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960006/3832970) in the linked thread.