# JavaScript DOMParser access innerHTML and other properties

Tags: javascript, dom, domparser

I am using the following code to parse a string into DOM:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/xml');
```

Where `string` is something like `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>content</body></html>`.

`typeof doc` gives me `object`. If I do something like `doc.querySelector('body')` I get a DOM object back. But if I try to access any properties, like you normally can, it gives me `undefined`:

```
doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML; // undefined
```

The same goes for other properties, e.g. `id`. The attribute retrieval on the other hand goes fine `doc.querySelector('body').getAttribute('id');`.

Is there a magic function to have access to those properties?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your current method fails, because HTML properties are not defined for the given XML document. If you supply the `text/html` MIME-type, the method should work.

```
var string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>content</body></html>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/html');
doc.body.innerHTML; // or doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML
// ^ Returns "content"
```

The code below enables the `text/html` MIME-type for browsers which do not natively support it yet. Is retrieved from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers):

```
/* 
 * DOMParser HTML extension 
 * 2012-02-02 
 * 
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com 
 * Public domain. 
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. 
 */  

/*! @source https://gist.github.com/1129031 */  
/*global document, DOMParser*/  

(function(DOMParser) {  
    "use strict";  
    var DOMParser_proto = DOMParser.prototype  
      , real_parseFromString = DOMParser_proto.parseFromString;

    // Firefox/Opera/IE throw errors on unsupported types  
    try {  
        // WebKit returns null on unsupported types  
        if ((new DOMParser).parseFromString("", "text/html")) {  
            // text/html parsing is natively supported  
            return;  
        }  
    } catch (ex) {}  

    DOMParser_proto.parseFromString = function(markup, type) {  
        if (/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(type)) {  
            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("")
              , doc_elt = doc.documentElement
              , first_elt;

            doc_elt.innerHTML = markup;
            first_elt = doc_elt.firstElementChild;

            if (doc_elt.childElementCount === 1
                && first_elt.localName.toLowerCase() === "html") {  
                doc.replaceChild(first_elt, doc_elt);  
            }  

            return doc;  
        } else {  
            return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);  
        }  
    };  
}(DOMParser));
```

Comment: PS. For clarification, when you're using `text/xml`, `doc` is an instance of `XMDocument`. Using `text/html`, it's an instance of `HTMLDocument`.

Comment: Waaw, quite a useful answer! Couldn't have found that one myself. Just the mime type and enabling that mime type :)

Comment: @RobW I assume you mean `XMLDocument`.

Comment: Thanks @RobW.  This was useful for the reverse process where one was able to use regex to edit a text string to add html and then build a replacement node [avoiding innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535762/1308424)  Your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: The solution is not bad but:
- Why are you using the coma operator and not just 3 instructions? this option is more "obscure" and does not add any advantage. Further more, the first_elt use create a global variable in the window scope (what is soo bad).

Comment: @AdrianMaire All variables are local, the comma's are part of the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) statement, not the comma operator. Note that I didn't write the code, and the code is not perfect. For instance, in Internet Explorer 9-, the code will fail because `document.documentElement.innerHTML` is read-only.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks you for the clarification.
As far as I know, document.implementation.createHTMLDocument is only available since IE9, so this code does not support any IE? Do you know any equivalent for IE6-8?
Anyway, it still useful for "complient" browsers like firefox.

Comment: @AdrianMaire It really depends on your purposes. A few months ago, I've written a `toDOM` method for the major 5 browsers, which should *not* load external resources. Initially, I tried to use a hidden iframe. The DOM is parsed well, but external resources are obviously loaded. In the end, I ended up using `document.createElement('html')` plus additional expando methods. And unless a significant part of your clients uses IE6/7, I strongly recommend to drop support for these browsers. Practically no-one uses them any more. Some argue that even IE8 may be ignored...

Comment: @RobW : Do you know where I can find a list of browsers which support`DOMParser().parseFromString()`but not with the`text/html`mime type?

Comment: @user2284570 All modern desktop browsers support this feature, including Chrome 30+, Firefox 12+, IE 10+, Opera 17+ and Safari 7.1+. This information is also available at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RobW : Currently, I’concerned by Opera Presto *(seems to work with XML documents)* (Blink versions can be considered as downgrades); and IE8/IE6, since many companies force their Users to use the preinstalled browser of XP *(the same way, they were still using 2000 in 2011)*.

Comment: @user2284570 `DOMParser`+`text/html` is not supported by Presto. The polyfill works almosy flawlessly though (one notable difference: With the polyfill, if you have `<img src>` in the HTML, then the image will be loaded). IE6-8 do not support `createHTMLDocument`, and I don't see why you want to support them, since Windows XP is already end-of-life (so no reason to use IE8 and definitely not IE 6). There is no solid alternative to `DOMParser`+`text/html`. You could use `document.createElement` and assign HTML to it (any external content (`<img src>`, styles, .) will also be parsed and loaded).

Comment: @RobW :`Windows XP is already end-of-life` Yes but some companies have even chosen to not upgrade. It may represent 8% of users *(I can’t check since logging with a proxy can be considered as an indirect law requirement for computers services here)*.

Comment: @devios1 [it used to return a Document instance](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument) though.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
```

whereas html is the string you want to convert.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution if you want also execute scripts, like:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/58862506/890357

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.getAttribute(attributeName)` for XML/HTML elements