# How to append a raw JavaScript tag to document.body without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I get a raw JavaScript tag from the server:

```
"<script>alert('hi');</script>"
```

Now, I need to append it to `<body>` so that it fires.  I can't simply create a new script element, because this string already contains the `<script>` part.  Is there something analogous to

```
child = document.createElementFromHTML("<script>alert('hi');</script>");
document.body.appendChild(child)
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

Here's why it's not a duplicate, hall monitors:

If you set the inner html of a div to be a script it won't fire.  I need to append an element generated from only text to the body.

EDIT 2

final solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.body.innerHTML += "<script>alert('hi');</script>";
var script = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.textContent = script.textContent;
document.body.removeChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: *"I can't simply create a new script element, because this string already contains the part."* What if you remove that part? `str.replace(/^<script>|<\/script>$/g, '')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new DOM element from an HTML string using built-in DOM methods or prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494143/creating-a-new-dom-element-from-an-html-string-using-built-in-dom-methods-or-pro)

Comment: i will never understand why people work for SO for free.  Good job, hall monitors.

Comment: `"/"` character at `"</script>"` within string should be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate `document.body.innerHTML` with `<script>` html string, get `.textContent` of last `script` in `document`, create `script` element, set `script` element `.textContent` to value retrieved from concatenated `html` `<script>` string, remove last `<script>`, append new `<script>` to `document.body`.

```html
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML += "<script>alert('hi');<\/script>");
  var script = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.textContent = script.textContent;
  document.body.removeChild(script);
  document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Comment: this is close, it assumes document.body is available, by wrapping this in document.onload it works, i'll add the final solution to the post, thanks for not being an SO dou che and dismissing my question, this is super helpful

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can insert `<script>` tag in your HTML

```js
var script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
script.text = 'alert("Hi!");'
```

Comment: this won't work because i don't know a priori what the script is, it comes from the server as a string.

Comment: Can you make the server return only alert("Hi!"); without the script tags. I mean only the script content without the tags.

Comment: no, but i wonder if i could use replace to strip out opening and closing tags

Comment: Yes that's a good idea or just try to get the inner code by breaking it on the basis of '<' brackets using split function.

Comment: i found this, it works, in that it does append the script, but the script doesn't fire, any idea why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334645/create-node-from-markup-string