# How to find elements inside an arbitrary chunk of HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm using observable mutations inside a Chrome extension and it's working well:

```
var insertedNodes = [];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        // loop through each chunk of html that changes on the page
        for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++){
            newHTMLChunk = mutation.addedNodes[i];
            //console.log(newHTMLChunk);
        }
    })
});
observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree:true
});
```

Inside each iteration (inside YouTube in this case), `newHTMLChunk` evaluates to a chunk of HTML like the following:

```
<li class="channels-content-item yt-shelf-grid-item">
   <div class="yt-lockup clearfix  yt-lockup-video yt-lockup-grid vve-check" data-context-item-id="Kky3wgURBJ0" data-visibility-tracking="QJ2JxKig-K2mKg==">
      <div class="yt-lockup-dismissable">
         <div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail">
            <span class=" spf-link  ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto">
               <a href="/watch?v=Kky3wgURBJ0" class="yt-uix-sessionlink" aria-hidden="true" data-sessionlink="ei=PkhhWMS-CoXMugKIxL_YDg&amp;feature=c4-videos-u">  <span class="video-thumb  yt-thumb yt-thumb-196">
               <span class="yt-thumb-default">
               <span class="yt-thumb-clip">
               <img alt="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Kky3wgURBJ0/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&amp;w=336&amp;h=188&amp;stc=true&amp;jpg444=true&amp;jpgq=90&amp;sp=68&amp;sigh=PSGK-mxzthJQOk44ZEKdd1jCrkA" onload=";__ytRIL(this)" width="196" data-ytimg="1" aria-hidden="true">
               ...more here ...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Get a handle to that `<img>` element. (It will be the only image element in the chunk of HTML.)
2. Get a handle to the `<div>` element that contains the `data-context-item-id` attribute. (In this particular case the value is `Kky3wgURBJ0`.)

Can jQuery find elements in an arbitrary chunk of html as shown above? Or can it only operate on an entire web page? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your doing something weird: why convert addedNodes to HTML if you can access it directly as DOM tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can jQuery find elements in an arbitrary chunk of html as shown above?

Yes, it can. Here is an example.

```
// create a container for your html
var $div = $('<div>')

// inject html
$div.html(newHTMLChunk)

// traverse
$div.find('div[data-context-item-id="Kky3wgURBJ0"]')
```

---

Edit: this can also be done without jQuery, using [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

See [Inserting arbitrary HTML into a DocumentFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284117/inserting-arbitrary-html-into-a-documentfragment)