# Strict HTML parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

On Google Chrome (Canary), it seems no string can make the DOM parser fail. I'm trying to parse some HTML, but if the HTML isn't completely, 100%, valid, I want it to display an error. I've tried the obvious:

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML = someMarkup; // Might fail on IE, never on Chrome.
```

I've also tried the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript). Doesn't fail for invalid markup, even the most invalid markup I can produce.

So, is there some way to parse HTML "strictly" in Google Chrome at least? I don't want to resort to tokenizing it myself or using an external validation utility. If there's no other alternative, a strict XML parser is fine, but certain elements don't require closing tags in HTML, and preferably those shouldn't fail.

Comment: "strict" in JavaScript has a [specific meaning](http://es5.github.com/#C), so I've edited the title of your question

Comment: *"...certain elements don't require closing tags in HTML..."* Some elements [don't require **opening** tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), either.

Comment: tried it with HTML doctype strict?

Comment: @powtac: I'm trying to parse HTML fragments - no DTD.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Okay - but the question remains :)

Comment: This might offer some clues (it's an extension, but I imagine it might help if there's source code): http://robertnyman.com/html-validator/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It delegates to the W3C validation service, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that (not sure about the inline one). At least initially, JS-Beautify seems to provide a number of errors: https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/blob/master/tests/sanitytest.js and it seems to use an internal tokenizer (although can't tell if it's server-based or if [this file](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/blob/master/beautify.js) performs it in-browser). I don't want to gum up the comments with any more suggestions though, so hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DOMParser` to check a document in two steps:

1. Validate whether the document is XML-conforming, by parsing it as XML.
2. Parse the string as HTML. This requires a [modification on the DOMParser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251106/938089?javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties).

   Loop through each element, and check whether the DOM element is an instance of `HTMLUnknownElement`. For this purpose, `getElementsByTagName('*')` fits well.
   (If you want to strictly parse the document, you have to recursively loop through each element, and remember whether the element is [allowed to be placed](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#kinds-of-content) at that location. Eg. `<area>` in `<map>`)

## Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q66Ep/1/

```
/* DOM parser for text/html, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251106/938089 */
;(function(DOMParser) {"use strict";var DOMParser_proto=DOMParser.prototype,real_parseFromString=DOMParser_proto.parseFromString;try{if((new DOMParser).parseFromString("", "text/html"))return;}catch(e){}DOMParser_proto.parseFromString=function(markup,type){if(/^\s*text\/html\s*(;|$)/i.test(type)){var doc=document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""),doc_elt=doc.documentElement,first_elt;doc_elt.innerHTML=markup;first_elt=doc_elt.firstElementChild;if (doc_elt.childElementCount===1&&first_elt.localName.toLowerCase()==="html")doc.replaceChild(first_elt,doc_elt);return doc;}else{return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);}};}(DOMParser));

/*
 * @description              Validate a HTML string
 * @param       String html  The HTML string to be validated 
 * @returns            null  If the string is not wellformed XML
 *                    false  If the string contains an unknown element
 *                     true  If the string satisfies both conditions
 */
function validateHTML(html) {
    var parser = new DOMParser()
      , d = parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0"?>'+html,'text/xml')
      , allnodes;
    if (d.querySelector('parsererror')) {
        console.log('Not welformed HTML (XML)!');
        return null;
    } else {
        /* To use text/html, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251106/938089 */
        d = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
        allnodes = d.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i=allnodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (allnodes[i] instanceof HTMLUnknownElement) return false;
        }
    }
    return true; /* The document is syntactically correct, all tags are closed */
}

console.log(validateHTML('<div>'));  //  null, because of the missing close tag
console.log(validateHTML('<x></x>'));// false, because it's not a HTML element
console.log(validateHTML('<a></a>'));//  true, because the tag is closed,
                                     //       and the element is a HTML element
```

*See [revision 1 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9354011/1) for an alternative to XML validation without the DOMParser.*

### Considerations

- The current method completely ignores the doctype, for validation.
- This method returns `null` for `<input type="text">`, while it's valid HTML5 (because the tag is not closed).
- Conformance is not checked.

Comment: It should be easier to parse XML with `DOMParser()`/`ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')`. Your construction doesn't validate against a DTD (or XML Schema), it only tries to parse this string as XML (and if it fails it throws an not well-formed error). In addition, at least Firefox uses a non-validating parser.

Comment: You should rename your function to `parseXHTML` or something similar. Parsing a SGMLDocument (or HTML5Document) isn't that simple. Your solution will return false at valid HTML strings like `<!DOCTYPE html ...><title></title><p>foo` and and true at invalid strings like `<p><li></li></p>`. [`document.querySelectorAll` is unbelievable slow compared to `document.getElementsByTagName`](http://jsperf.com/get-all-elements)

Comment: @Saxoier I had already adressed both inabilities at the top of the answer. I have also added them at the bottom of the answer, in case you don't see it. As for QSA vs GTA, that's true.

Comment: I know you wrote it at the top. But why do you call this function `validateHTML`. Neither does the function except HTML nor can it validate XML (or XHTML).

Comment: @Saxoier This can be used as a base for HTML validation, as pointed out at note 2. However, I am not going to write and test a full validator, because that's time-consuming, and not going to be anything special.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get notified about this answer for some reason :S Thank you, I've found a different way since, but I'll mark this as the answer.