# Parse an HTML string with JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I want to parse a string which contains HTML text. I want to do it in JavaScript.

I tried the [Pure JavaScript HTML Parser library](https://johnresig.com/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/) but it seems that it parses the HTML of my current page, not from a string. Because when I try the code below, it changes the title of my page:

```
var parser = new HTMLtoDOM("<html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body><a href='test0'>test01</a><a href='test1'>test02</a><a href='test2'>test03</a></body></html>", document);
```

My goal is to extract links from an HTML external page that I read just like a string.

Do you know an API to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript DOMParser access innerHTML and other properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties)

Comment: The method on the linked duplicate creates a HTML document from a given string. Then, you can use `doc.getElementsByTagName('a')` to read the links (or even [`doc.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links)).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you're using a framework like React.js then there may be ways of doing it that are specific to the framework such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Create a dummy DOM element and add the string to it. Then, you can manipulate it like any DOM element.

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = "<html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body><a href='test0'>test01</a><a href='test1'>test02</a><a href='test2'>test03</a></body></html>";

el.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ); // Live NodeList of your anchor elements
```

Edit: adding a jQuery answer to please the fans!

```
var el = $( '<div></div>' );
el.html("<html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body><a href='test0'>test01</a><a href='test1'>test02</a><a href='test2'>test03</a></body></html>");

$('a', el) // All the anchor elements
```

Comment: Just a note:
With this solution, if I do a "alert(el.innerHTML)", I lose the <html>, <body> and <head> tag....

Comment: Problem:
I need to get links from <frame> tag. But with this solution, the frame tag are deleted...

Comment: You can clone the `<frame>` and work on the clone. This way, you keep the original untouched and work on the cloned element (which you can delete/whatever). To clone, you can use: `var c = el.cloneNode( true );` or with jQuery: `var c = $( el ).clone();`.

Comment: I think I didn't understand because when I try it, it doesn't work:
var c = el.cloneNode( true );
alert(c.innerHTML);
The frame tag is still deleted

Comment: It does work in there: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/nkPjp/ . If what you want is getting elements from an `iframe` on another domain, then it is not possible for security reasons.

Comment: I've got this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aHWJ8/
i cannot grap the link ? as you can see, even the <body>, <head>, <html> are deleted.

Comment: The link is in the "src" of the frame. <FRAME SRC='web-pages/page.html'>

Comment: Well, that's completely different from what your question states. You should ask another question for this.

Comment: But the problem is that you can't do that. Even jQuery will strip off the `frame` tags, since it's just using `innerHTML`. I don't think using frames is a good idea btw.

Comment: But this is what I asked: "My goal is to extract links from a HTML external page that I read just like a String."
I extract links from <img>, <script>, <a>... I just miss FRAME because it's deleted by the innerHTML method.

Comment: In an HTML page, a link is an `anchor` tag (a), that's how everybody answered you :-). You can't get the FRAME source. innerHTML is the only way to do this, so you can't do it. Your only way would be to send the html server side with ajax so that you can work with it.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer that involves vanilla Javascript! Almost in 99.999% of the cases there's no need to use jQuery! Occasionally, I get lazy and use $.get/post, but that's it.

Comment: @stage I'm a little bit late to the party, but you should be able to use `document.createElement('html');` to preserve the `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: I was afraid for ID collision, but this did not happen. Just in case another newbie was wondering the same thing.

Comment: it looks like you are putting an html element within an html element

Comment: In my case, my page needs to repeat this activity over and over again. Would repeatedly creating a dummy dom element get memory intensive? Is there a way to dispose of the dom element once the innerHtml has been extracted? I'm not quite familiar with how the browser handles javascript variables.

Comment: I'm concerned is upvoted as the top answer.  The [`parse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/#55046067) solution below is more reusable and elegant.

Comment: Security note: this will execute any script in the input, and thus is unsuitable for untrusted input.

Comment: That's not an ideal solution, since if the html string contains images for example, the browser will try to fetch them! So this is a side effect of the parsing that we may not want: See this example: var html = "<div><img src=\"img_girl.jpg\" width=\"500\" height=\"600\"></div>";
var div           = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML     = html;

Comment: I can imagine that `html` is twice there, it is `created` and then `used` in `innerHtml`.

Comment: Doesn't work if you're going to work on the DOM afterwards (at least in Firefox). Doing `el.ownerDocument.getElementById('some-id-with-new-html').innerHTML` returns the old HTML instead of the new.

Comment: If you don't want it to load images and whatnot, use a DOMParser (see other answers)

Comment: Hey @FlorianMargaine  This script is giving error    This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment.  Can I please know how to solve this

Answer (score 421):

It's quite simple:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');
// do whatever you want with htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser#Browser_compatibility), to do this in chrome you need to parse as XML like so:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/xml');
// do whatever you want with htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

<s>It is currently unsupported by webkit and you'd have to follow Florian's answer, and it is unknown to work in most cases on mobile browsers.</s>

Edit: Now widely supported

Comment: Worth noting that in 2016 DOMParser is now widely supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer

Comment: Worth noting that all relative links in the created document are broken, because the document gets created by inheriting the `documentURL` of `window`, which most likely differs from the URL of the string.

Comment: Worth noting that you should *only* call `new DOMParser` once and then reuse that same object throughout the rest of your script.

Comment: The [`parse()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js#55046067) solution below is more reusable and specific to HTML.  This is nice if you need an XML document, however.

Comment: How can I display this parsed webpage on a dialog box or something? I was not able to find solution for that

Comment: Security note: this will execute without any browser context, so no scripts will run. It should be suitable for untrusted input.

Comment: how to convert HTML to string using javascript?

Comment: @HardikMandankaa `html` `IS` a string, so no need to convert. It is already there as string rep.

Comment: Since chrome 31, `text/html` is possible. I wonder if there is anybody using this version of chrome or lower..

Answer (score 42):

EDIT: The solution below is only for HTML "fragments" since html,head and body are removed. I guess the solution for this question is DOMParser's parseFromString() method:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
```

---

For HTML fragments, the solutions listed here works for most HTML, however for certain cases it won't work.

For example try parsing `<td>Test</td>`. This one won't work on the div.innerHTML solution nor DOMParser.prototype.parseFromString nor range.createContextualFragment solution. The td tag goes missing and only the text remains.

Only jQuery handles that case well.

So the future solution (MS Edge 13+) is to use template tag:

```
function parseHTML(html) {
    var t = document.createElement('template');
    t.innerHTML = html;
    return t.content;
}

var documentFragment = parseHTML('<td>Test</td>');
```

For older browsers I have extracted jQuery's parseHTML() method into an independent gist - https://gist.github.com/Munawwar/6e6362dbdf77c7865a99

Comment: If you want to write forward-compatible code that also works on old browsers you can [polyfill the `<template>` tag](https://github.com/webcomponents/template). It depends on custom elements which you may also need to [polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements). In fact you might just want to use [webcomponents.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) to polyfill custom elements, templates, shadow dom, promises, and a few other things all at one go.

Comment: Wow. Extremely efficient!

Answer (score 30):

```js
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var links = doc.querySelectorAll("a");
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing `$`? Also, as mentioned in the [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250545/javascript-domparser-access-innerhtml-and-other-properties), `text/html` is not supported very well, and has to be implemented using a polyfill.

Comment: I copied this line from a project, I'm used to prefix variables with $ in javascript application (not in library). it's just to avoir having a conflict with a library. that's not very usefull as almost every variable is scoped but it used to be usefull. it also (maybe) help to identify variables easily.

Comment: Sadly `DOMParser` neither work on `text/html` in chrome, [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser#DOMParser_HTML_extension_for_other_browsers) gives workaround.

Comment: Security note: this will execute without any browser context, so no scripts will run. It should be suitable for untrusted input.

Answer (score 8):

```
const parse = Range.prototype.createContextualFragment.bind(document.createRange());

document.body.appendChild( parse('<p><strong>Today is:</strong></p>') ),
document.body.appendChild( parse(`<p style="background: #eee">${new Date()}</p>`) );
```

---

Only valid child `Node`s within the parent `Node` (start of the `Range`) will be parsed. Otherwise, unexpected results may occur:

```
// <body> is "parent" Node, start of Range
const parseRange = document.createRange();
const parse = Range.prototype.createContextualFragment.bind(parseRange);

// Returns Text "1 2" because td, tr, tbody are not valid children of <body>
parse('<td>1</td> <td>2</td>');
parse('<tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td></tr>');
parse('<tbody><tr><td>1</td> <td>2</td></tr></tbody>');

// Returns <table>, which is a valid child of <body>
parse('<table> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </table>');
parse('<table> <tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tr> </table>');
parse('<table> <tbody> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tbody> </table>');

// <tr> is parent Node, start of Range
parseRange.setStart(document.createElement('tr'), 0);

// Returns [<td>, <td>] element array
parse('<td>1</td> <td>2</td>');
parse('<tr> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tr>');
parse('<tbody> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </tbody>');
parse('<table> <td>1</td> <td>2</td> </table>');
```

Comment: Security note: this will execute any script in the input, and thus is unsuitable for untrusted input.

Answer (score 7):

The following function `parseHTML` will return either :

- a [**`Document`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) when your file starts with a doctype.
- a [**`DocumentFragment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) when your file doesn't start with a doctype.

---

#### The code :

```
function parseHTML(markup) {
    if (markup.toLowerCase().trim().indexOf('<!doctype') === 0) {
        var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
        doc.documentElement.innerHTML = markup;
        return doc;
    } else if ('content' in document.createElement('template')) {
       // Template tag exists!
       var el = document.createElement('template');
       el.innerHTML = markup;
       return el.content;
    } else {
       // Template tag doesn't exist!
       var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
       var el = document.createElement('body');
       el.innerHTML = markup;
       for (i = 0; 0 < el.childNodes.length;) {
           docfrag.appendChild(el.childNodes[i]);
       }
       return docfrag;
    }
}
```

---

#### How to use :

```
var links = parseHTML('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><a>Link 1</a><a>Link 2</a></body></html>').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on IE8. I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" for the first line in the function. I don't think the createHTMLDocument function exists

Comment: What exactly is your use case? If you just want to parse HTML and your HTML is intended for the body of your document, you could do the following : (1) var div=document.createElement("DIV"); (2) div.innerHTML = markup; (3) result = div.childNodes; --- This gives you a collection of childnodes and should work not just in IE8 but even in IE6-7.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate option, I'll try it if I need to do this again. For now though I used the JQuery solution above.

Comment: @SebastianCarroll Note that IE8 doesn't support the `trim` method on strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2308134/3210837.

Comment: @Toothbrush : Is IE8 support still relevant at the dawn of 2017?

Comment: @JohnSlegers For some companies, yes.

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to parse HTML in Chrome and Firefox is Range#createContextualFragment:

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.body); // required in Safari
var fragment = range.createContextualFragment('<h1>html...</h1>');
var firstNode = fragment.firstChild;
```

I would recommend to create a helper function which uses createContextualFragment if available and falls back to innerHTML otherwise.

Benchmark: http://jsperf.com/domparser-vs-createelement-innerhtml/3

Comment: Note that, like (the simple) `innerHTML`, this will execute an `<img>`’s `onerror`.

Comment: An issue with this is that, html like '<td>test</td>' would ignore the td in the document.body context (and only create 'test' text node).OTOH, if it used internally in a templating engine then the right context would be available.

Comment: Also BTW, IE 11 supports createContextualFragment.

Comment: The question was how to parse with JS - not Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Security note: this will execute any script in the input, and thus is unsuitable for untrusted input.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way is use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) API like this:

```js
//Table string in HTML format
const htmlString = '<table><tbody><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></tbody></table>';

//Parse using DOMParser native way
const parser = new DOMParser();
const $newTable = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

//Here you can select parts of your parsed html and work with it
const $row = $newTable.querySelector('table > tbody > tr');

//Here i'm printing the number of columns (2)
const $containerHtml = document.getElementById('containerHtml');
$containerHtml.innerHTML = ['Your parsed table have ', $row.cells.length, 'columns.'].join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="containerHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**1 Way**

Use `document.cloneNode()`

Performance is:

Call to `document.cloneNode()` took ~0.22499999977299012 milliseconds.

and maybe will be more.

```js
var t0, t1, html;

t0 = performance.now();
   html = document.cloneNode(true);
t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

html.documentElement.innerHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="test1">test1</div></body></html>';

console.log(html.getElementById("test1"));
```

**2 Way**

Use `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()`

Performance is:

Call to `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` took ~0.14000000010128133 milliseconds.

```js
var t0, t1, html;

t0 = performance.now();
html = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("test");
t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

html.documentElement.innerHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="test1">test1</div></body></html>';

console.log(html.getElementById("test1"));
```

**3 Way**

Use `document.implementation.createDocument()`

Performance is:

Call to `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` took ~0.14000000010128133 milliseconds.

```
var t0 = performance.now();
  html = document.implementation.createDocument('', 'html', 
             document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '')
         );
var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

html.documentElement.innerHTML = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="test1">test</div></body></html>';

console.log(html.getElementById("test1"));
```

**4 Way**

Use `new Document()`

Performance is:

Call to `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` took ~0.13499999840860255 milliseconds.

- Note

`ParentNode.append` is experimental technology in 2020 year.

```js
var t0, t1, html;

t0 = performance.now();
//---------------
html = new Document();

html.append(
  html.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '')
);
    
html.append(
  html.createElement('html')
);
//---------------
t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

html.documentElement.innerHTML = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><div id="test1">test1</div></body></html>';

console.log(html.getElementById("test1"));
```

Answer (score 5):

To do this in node.js, you can use an HTML parser like [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser). The syntax looks like this:

```js
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';

const root = parse('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>');

console.log(root.firstChild.structure);
// ul#list
//   li
//     #text

console.log(root.querySelector('#list'));
// { tagName: 'ul',
//   rawAttrs: 'id="list"',
//   childNodes:
//    [ { tagName: 'li',
//        rawAttrs: '',
//        childNodes: [Object],
//        classNames: [] } ],
//   id: 'list',
//   classNames: [] }
console.log(root.toString());
// <ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>
root.set_content('<li>Hello World</li>');
root.toString();    // <li>Hello World</li>
```

Comment: This is the best solution even on the browser, if you do not want to rely on the browser implementation.. This implementation will behave always the same no matter which browser you are on (not that it matters much nowdays), but also the parsing is done in javascript itself instead of c/c++!

Comment: Thanks @Rainb. How do you use the solution in the browser though?

Comment: like this `(await import("https://cdn.skypack.dev/node-html-parser")).default('<ul id="list"><li>Hello World</li></ul>').firstChild.structure`

Comment: I never knew that was an option. Can you do that with any node library, or is it because this one doesn't use any node-only code?

Comment: if it requires anything from node like tls, http, net, fs then it probably won't work in the browser. But it won't work in deno either. So just look for deno compatible packages.

Answer (score 4):

If you're open to using jQuery, it has some nice facilities for creating detached DOM elements from strings of HTML. These can then be queried through the usual means, E.g.:

```
var html = "<html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body><a href='test0'>test01</a><a href='test1'>test02</a><a href='test2'>test03</a></body></html>";
var anchors = $('<div/>').append(html).find('a').get();
```

---

Edit - just saw @Florian's answer which is correct. This is basically exactly what he said, but with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
const html =
`<script>
    alert(' there ! Wanna grab a '); 
</script>`;

const scriptEl = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
parent.append(scriptEl);
```

I found this solution, and i think it's the best solution, it parse the HTML and execute the script inside.

Answer (score 1):

I used DOMParser class which I referred from this blog.

This will return a HTMLCollection object where we can access the element as DOM element itself. Also easy to insert the code in the HTML document by
`document.body.append(...parseHTML(html_string));`

```
const parseHTML = (htmlString) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const page = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
    return page.body.children;
};
```

Thank me later.

Comment: this worked for me, but I used `page.body` because I needed to query for a specific element and I had an issue doing that when also selecting `children`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use innerHTML of an element parsed in popover of Angular NGX Bootstrap popover. This is the solution which worked for me.

`public htmlContainer = document.createElement( 'html' );`

in constructor

`this.htmlContainer.innerHTML = ''; setTimeout(() => { this.convertToArray(); });`

```
 convertToArray() {
    const shapesHC = document.getElementsByClassName('weekPopUpDummy');
    const shapesArrHCSpread = [...(shapesHC as any)];
    this.htmlContainer = shapesArrHCSpread[0];
    this.htmlContainer.innerHTML = shapesArrHCSpread[0].textContent;
  }
```

in html

```
<div class="weekPopUpDummy" [popover]="htmlContainer.innerHTML" [adaptivePosition]="false" placement="top" [outsideClick]="true" #popOverHide="bs-popover" [delay]="150" (onHidden)="onHidden(weekEvent)" (onShown)="onShown()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parseElement(raw){
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = raw;
    let res = el.querySelector('*');
    res.remove();
    return res;
}
```

> note: raw string should not be more than 1 element

Answer (score -1):

```
let content = "<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>"
let result = $("<div/>").html(content).text()
```

content: `<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>`,
result: `"404 Not Found"`

Comment: This does not answer the Quest. OP wants to extract links.