# jQuery remove tag from HTML String without RegEx

Tags: jquery, html, string

So I have following string:

```
var s = '<span>Some Text</span> Some other Text';
```

The result should be a string with the content "Some other Text".

I tried...

```
var $s = $(s).not('span');
```

...and a lot of other stuff with `remove()`, `not()`, etc. but nothing worked.

Any suggestions? I could match the string with regex, but I prefer a common jQuery solution.

**edit:**

I do **not** search a solution with regex, I'm just wondering why this example does not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/q9crX/150/

Comment: did you actually add that html to the DOM somewhere? You need to add it before you can select it using jQuery

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can wrap your `string` in a jQuery object and do some sort of a manipulation like this:

```
var removeElements = function(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector).remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var removedSpanString = removeElements("<span>Some Text</span> Some other Text", "span");
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can specify a jquery selector which to remove. i.e. you may wish to remove the `<th>` in a string. This would be very handy in that case. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok thank you, this one worked ans isn't a regex! :)
But check out the edit of my question, maybe there is a solution for my jsfiddle-example as well.

Answer (score 15):

A very simple approach:

```
var html = '<span>Remove <b>tags &amp; entities</b></span>';
var noTagText = $(html).text();
// ==> noTagText = 'Remove tags & entities'
```

Note that it will remove tags but also html entities.

Answer (score 11):

This may suit your needs:

```
<([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?</\1>|<[^/]+/>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1gmcSdz9s3MSimVQ)

In JavaScript:

```js
$s = s.replace(/<([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>|<[^\/]+\/>/ig, "");
```

It also removes self-closing tags (e.g. `<br />`).

Comment: I feel like writing regex parsers for anything with an existing parser usually means you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @bytesized You're absolutely right, I wouldn't have answered this question that way nowadays.

Comment: Great debuggex visualization!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Just remove html tag like this

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YQPsz/3/)

```
var s = '<span>Some Text</span> Some other Text';
var r = /<(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>/gi;
s.replace(r,"");
```

Answer given over here :http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=252483

Comment: @sp00m - thanks for into but wokrs with given input..its need to modify as op want

Comment: Yes this regex is really great :)
It should work for me, but I still have this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9crX/150/

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because I don't believe that using regex to parse HTML is valid. Especially when this question is using jQuery which can easily manipulate the DOM nodes.

Comment: This provides a better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js/10585079#10585079

Answer (score 3):

Just do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("span").not("span div").each(
 function(index, element) {
$("span").remove();
 }
 );
 });

</script>

<span>Some Text</span> Some other Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Gcb/)

e.g. More Specific to your case :-

```
var s = '<span>Some Text</span> Some other Text';
var $s = s.replace(/<span>(.*)<\/span>/g, "");
```