# jqueryte text editor. How to remove certain HTML tags that are posted in "source code"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqte

I want users to be able to use the editor or paste source HTML, but I want to link which tags are allowed (not img, a, etc).

How can I set jQueryTE to remove these tags, or all tags that aren't on my approved tag list?

Comment: You can check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109946/jquery-remove-tag-from-html-string.
here also mentioned answer for certail html tags.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YQPsz/3/

Comment: @sehtaumesh Can JQTE not handle it directly?

Comment: You need to remove html tags before setting the value of textarea and after that apply jqte on textarea.