# How to make a word count that contains html tags using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rich-text-editor, word-count

Hi I would like to do a Word Count in my RTE (Rich Text Editor) with javascript can also use with jquery. But it should not count the html tags and repeating white spaces.

Sample Text:

`<p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>`

The javascript should display 5 only.

Is there any javascript code for this and that is also fast to calculate the Word Count?

Thanks!

Comment: have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14010497/622287

Comment: @kevnk I tried the accepted answer and it gives me this different result after pasting my sample text: 
Characters (no spaces): 39
Characters (and spaces): 41
Words: 3
Lines: 1

Comment: This can be done with jQuery.text() and String.split() and the Array.length property.  Probably in one line.

Comment: thanks @tpdietz but do you have any idea how will it be?

Comment: @howardtyler what have you tried already?

Comment: Hi @SamHood I tried this code but I get 3: var length = $(".text").text().trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
console.log(length);

Comment: @howardtyler check out the accepted answer to this, could be helpful in what you're trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109946/jquery-remove-tag-from-html-string

Comment: @howardtyler You can use [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/rvkw0jfz/) but i don't know about brwoser support of `innerText`.

Comment: @Mohammad Looks like it's all good! But perhaps not necessarily reliable http://caniuse.com/#search=innerText

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try something like this:
You get the html in the div then you remove all tags and replace them with spaces. You remove (trim) all left and right spaces and finally you split the string into an array. The length is your answer.

```js
var cont = $("#content").html();
cont = cont.replace(/<[^>]*>/g," ");
cont = cont.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
cont = cont.trim();
var n = cont.split(" ").length
alert(n);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>
```

Comment: hi @roxoradev this is great! more organized. Can you explain the code you did there specificaly the regex you did because I want to learn what's the meaning of your regex there. Thanks! :)

Comment: The first regex include html tags that get replaced with blank spaces. The second regex delete multiple spaces for example a   b -> a b. If you think i helped you, you could mark this answer as the solution. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

```js
  var words = [];
  function getWords(elements) {
    elements.contents().each(function() {
      if ($(this).contents().length > 0) return getWords($(this));
      if ($(this).text()) words = words.concat($(this).text().split(" "));
    })

  }

  getWords($('<div>').html('<p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>'));
  console.log(words,words.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @vladu lonut thanks but it should be 5. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something tricky by using jQuery by creating an element with the content.

```js
var str = '<p>11 22&nbsp; 33</p><p>44</p>5<br></div>';

var len = 0;
// create a temporary jQuery object with the content
$('<div/>', {
    html: str
  })
  // get al child nodes including text node
  .contents()
  // iterate over the elements
  .each(function() {
    // now get number or words using match and add 
    len += (this.textContent.match(/[\w\d]+/g) || '').length;
  });

console.log(len);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @pranav C Balan this is awesome thanks! Can you explain what make it work? because I would like to learn more of js techniques. And also for others to understand how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Countable.js for live word counting, although it doesn't ignore HTML tags.