# Convert HTML object back to string

Tags: jquery, html, string, dom

I convert a string of HTML into an object so I can manipulate like this

```
var HTMLStr = "<div><span>TESTING</span></div><h1>HEADING</h1><div class='two'>sjdufhs</div>";
var HTMLDom = $(HTMLStr).find("h1").remove();
var newHTMLStr = ???
```

Question: How can I convert the HTMLDom back into a string after manipulation?

I have tried the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/652771/3758078
But that only converts the first element found, and not the rest. Especially if theres no element containing all other elements.

Comment: Only the first element found and not the rest. Sounds like you need a loop.

Comment: What is your current output from using that question, and what did you expect?

Comment: The output is: '<div></div>' as a string and not the other elements. The example HTML string above is a simplified version. I expected an HTML string identical to HTMLStr variable, but with the <h1> element removed.

Comment: I was about to answer, but then found that my answer already exists here: [jQuery remove tag from HTML-String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109946/jquery-remove-tag-from-html-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the result of parsing the HTML into a variable, so you can get its HTML after modifying it.

You also need to wrap the original HTML in another element, because getting the HTML later with `.html()` will only return the HTML of the first element in the collection.

```js
var HTMLStr = "<div><span>TESTING</span></div><h1>HEADING</h1><div class='two'>sjdufhs</div>";
var DOM = $('<div>' + HTMLStr + '</div>');
DOM.find("h1").remove();
var newHTMLStr = DOM.html();
console.log(newHTMLStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks, I fixed that.