# Convert html encoded string back into html elements jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stored some html contents into a div for later processing.

When I retrieve the contents back (using `$(".MyDiv").html()`) & display it else-where in the page, contents are html encoded.

I tried using `jQuery.parseHTML()` method to decode this string, but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**
I was using `jQuery template` to store the data in div, which by default encoded the string, I had to suppress encoding behavior. using following template, while binding.

```
{{html Response}}
```

Comment: How are you trying to display the HTML?  If you pass it into another call to the jQuery `.html()` function, that'll undo the encoding.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the "contents". If you're just trying to store some data, try using .data() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/252675

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example. You just pass it into the other jQuery object's html function.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/99h45/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="someInfo">Hello, this is a simple example.<p>Boom, a paragraph.</p></div>

<div id="storeHereLater"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
$(function(){
   var someInfoHTML = $('#someInfo').html();

    $('#storeHereLater').html(someInfoHTML);
});
```