# Using JS/Jquery .replace() to replace a multi line block of text/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am working on a project where I need to extract a block of HTML from a file, make adjustments to the extracted HTML, and then replace the HTML in the file with the updated HTML.  I am currently able to extract the HTML blocks that I want, but I am unable to replace them in the HTML file.  I have been working mainly in JS/Jquery right now, I haven't gotten to the writing the file out yet, that's not in the scope of this issue.

I have tried dumping the block of HTML into a variable and using it in the follow fashion:

`var removeThis = containerCopy.find('.keepMe, #showAlerts').remove().end().html();
var changed = containerMarkup.replace("/"+removeThis+"/gm", "<div>Replaced</div>");`

I have also tried with out the regex formatting.

`var changed = containerMarkup.replace(removeThis, "<div>Replaced</div>");`

I have tried using regex to replace white spaces & line breaks, and also to escape special characters in both the extracted block & the initial block.  Then running the replace.  This still didn't work.

The above were all options I found through other SO posts, but I am still unable to get the replace to work.  You can view a basic breakdown in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jspell/63Ppd/3/).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [**TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using a parser to interpret your markup.  This should make traversing and manipulating its contents much easier and safer than using regexps, etc.

Here is a random example from SO:
[Parse a HTML String with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js)

Note that jQuery is optional.

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
$('body').children().not('.keepMe, #showAlerts').remove();
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63Ppd/4/)