# how to replace every letter of a string without html tag in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My Code is given below,

```
var str = '<p>(a) test  <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">
test</span>&nbsp;<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
123 test&nbsp;<span style="font-family: SutonnyMJ;"> test test &nbsp;
<span style="background-color: #008000;">test&nbsp;<span style="background-color: #ffffff;">
&nbsp;test <span style="color: #800080;">test</span></span></span></span></span></p>
<table style="height: 43px;" width="250"><tbody><tr><td>test</td>
<td>test</td></tr></tbody></table>';

for(var eq in G){
    var an=new RegExp(eq,"g");
    str=str.replace(an,G[eq]); //For Example an = /t/g and G[eq] = a For One Index 
}
```

If i use this string without HTML Tag , the result is perfect.

I want to make a regular express pattern -

```
1. it will not replace any HTML Tag(
Example:<p>,</p> <div>,</div>,&nbsp;,<br/>,<span>,</span>,<table>,</table> and etc) 
and HTML Tag Atrribute(Example : style etc).
2. it will not replace inner/element of HTML Tag(Eexample : span,div etc) if font-fmaily 
is not SutonnyMJ (font-family: SutonnyMJ) in style attribute ;
```

I assume that **test** will be **abca** after replace.

The Result String is given below ,

```
result_str ='<p>(a) abca <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">
abcd </span>&nbsp;<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
123 test&nbsp;<span style="font-family: SutonnyMJ;"> abca abca &nbsp;
<span style="background-color: #008000;">abca&nbsp;<span style="background-color: #ffffff;">
&nbsp;test <span style="color: #800080;">abca</span></span></span></span></span></p>
<table style="height: 43px;" width="250"><tbody><tr><td>abca</td>
<td>abca</td></tr></tbody></table>';
```

In result_str **123 test** is not change because it's parent style font family is not **SutonnyMJ**

How to write a JavaScript regular expression pattern.
Please any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you an HTML parser instead of regex.

Comment: My Language Converter is working Nince without HTML Tag. But HTML tag have to work in result string.

Comment: the quotes " are incorrect...... try use single quotes for the string definition... or escape (with backslash) the double-quotes in the string.

Comment: @JLILI Aman , How to parse using HTML parser. You can say it which i would like to the code.

Comment: @MD.ABDULHalim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Answer (score 1):

A starting point to the pattern could be this:

```
(?:<[^\>]>)+(?:[^.]*(test)[^.]*)+(?:<\/[^\>]>)*
```

Replace `test` with your string.

**What's missing is the limitation, that the font-family should not be SutonnyMJ. **

Fiddle around and improve it here:
**http://regexr.com/3aj63**

Comment: Your pattern is selected all string but if i use p instead of test , it will select all p without <p> Tag.

Comment: Take the selection group as result

Comment: Actually since HTML tag have to work result string. Now  I need  content text of HTML tag. You could show me in  http://regexr.com which text will be only selected but not HTML Tag.

Comment: What did you try so far to do that in rexexr? actually the selection group does only select the text. I am not 100% sure about what you want to achieve, the regexr helps you to find a solution by reading the cheatsheet and documentation.

Comment: Yes, i can get only text using $(str).text(). But I have to translate one language to another language which if HTML Table/text design(using style attribute) is exist in input string. After converting the string , HTML Table/text design must be shown in the result string. I have JavaScript script for converting/translating language which is converting / translating string letter by letter. If i use $(str).text , i don't get HTML Table/text design in result string. If i get my wanted pattern ,then it is possible. Am i clear to you.