# can't filter HTML tag in HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable containing a long string of HTML code

```
var myHTML = "<html lang='en'><head><title>hey</title></head><body></body></html>"
```

I'm selecting tags within that string and getting their info like this

```
$(myHTML).filter("title").text();
```

that returns the text within the title tag. I've been able to filter and get other tags except for the HTML tag. For some reason this does not work `$(myHTML).filter("html").attr("lang")` I'm trying to get the lang attribute value in the HTML tag.

Comment: have you tried `$(myHTML).attr("lang")` ?

Comment: Because it's a **string** and not a DOM yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is filtering out the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags and only wrapping the `<title>` tag, which is leading to the behavior you're seeing.

Here is an example that uses the native `DOMParser` object to create a new document object and pull the tag out of that.

**Live Example:**

```js
var myHTML = "<html lang='en'><head><title>hey</title></head><body></body></html>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(myHTML, "text/xml");
var lang = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");

$("body").append(lang);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/0bu0jdy3/

---

[Credit to user The Wobbuffet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870431/2234742) for this method.

Comment: Nice explanation and solution! For further reference, see [DOMParser @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: I like this. Can this be mixed with jquery? for example can I do this htmlDoc.find("div"); ?

Comment: @pingykricky Just tried it out and it looks like `$(htmlDoc).find("html").attr("lang")` works. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bu0jdy3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Although I know someone will shout at me for this suggestion, I would use regex. I believe it's a valid use case, since the text pattern is regular.

```js
var myHTML = "<html lang='en'><head><title>hey</title></head><body></body></html>";
var lang = /html lang='(\w+)'/.exec(myHTML)[1];

alert(lang);
```