# How to parse html stored as variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html snippet like this stored in a variable for example

```
var parse= 'Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World'
```

Now I want to parse this html and it must grab the value of the title and replace the tag only with the title then return the result like this using javaScript or jQuery

```
var parsed = Hello:smile::angry:world
```

Can anyone point me towards right direction on how I can do it? So that I can work it out?

Comment: Please tell me parse content you will get from some html content. for ex <div> Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World</div>

Comment: Yeah your example is good!

Comment: have your tried jQuery.parseHtml() ?

Comment: @user2415266 No, I don't have much knowledge about it, tried using it after reading the docs but couldnt figure out much, can you give me a small example, so that I can implement and get back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a HTML String with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap it in a container and map it to join it. Well, that would give:

```js
var parse= 'Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World';

var parsed = $('<div/>', {html:parse}).contents().map(function(){
   return this.title || this.nodeValue;
}).get().join('');

$('body').append(parsed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `replace` method with regexp:

```
var parse= 'Hello<i class="emoji emoji_smile" title=":smile:"></i><i class="emoji emoji_angry" title=":angry:"></i>World'

var result = parse.replace(/<i.*?title="(.*?)"><\/i>?/g, "$1");

console.log(result); //Hello:smile::angry:World
```

Here a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ste8s7eL/

Comment: this works too thank you so much. Can you recommend some nice resource to learn regex for noobs?

Comment: This article is a good beginning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp. I use this http://regexr.com/ too, very useful :)