# Why does this regex take so long to execute?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I created `regex` that's supposed to move text inide of an adjoining `<span>` tag.

```
const fix = (string) => string.replace(/([\S]+)*<span([^<]+)*>(.*?)<\/span>([\S]+)*/g, "<span$2>$1$3$4</span>")

fix('<p>Given <span class="label">Butter</span>&#39;s game, the tree counts as more than one input.</p>')
// Results in:
'<p>Given <span class="label">Butter&#39;s</span> game, the tree counts as more than one input.</p>'
```

But if I pass it a string where there is no text touching a `<span>` tag, it takes a few seconds to run.

I'm testing this on `Chrome` and `Electron`.

Comment: HTML parsing with regex? Hmm.

Comment: If you are concerned only with `span` use this :- `<span([^<]+)>(.*?)<\/span>`..https://regex101.com/r/fL9rG0/1

Comment: also I see `([^<]+)*` an extra `*` which I don't think is needed

Comment: If you don't have inner elements, replace `(.*?)` with `([^<]*)`. This will be much faster

Comment: one more thing :- your regex is having catastrophic backtracking if `</span>` is not present

Comment: Don't do this is the best answer. Use any of the [methods for parsing HTML in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js).

Comment: @tadman, can you prove that it's faster to parse the html, manipulate it, and compile it into a string again?

Comment: @demux The performance characteristics of a regular expression of this sort is wildly unpredictable. On some strings it might be faster, but on others it might jam up and take literally forever. I guarantee that the DOMParser solution will produce *consistent* results even if they're not as performant. If this is only running hundreds of times that cost is utterly irrelevant. If this is running frequently then I'd be extremely concerned about using that regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`([\S]+)*` and `([^<]+)*` are the culprits that causes [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when there is no `</span>`. You need to modify your regex to

```
([\S]*)<span([^<]*)>(.*?)<\/span>([\S]*)
```

It will work but its still not [efficient](https://regex101.com/r/fL9rG0/2).

Why use character class for `\S`? The above reduces to

```
(\S*)<span([^<]*)>(.*?)<\/span>(\S*)
```

If you are concerned only about content of `span`, use this instead

```
<span([^<]*)>(.*?)<\/span>
```

Check **[here](https://regex101.com/r/fL9rG0/3)** <= (See the reduction in number of steps)

**NOTE** : At last don't parse HTML with regex, if there are tools that can do it much more easily

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @demux i am writing it

Comment: The point is to move text that is touching the `span` into the `span`, so no, I'm not only concerned about the contents

Comment: @demux then you can use the second one with capturing groups

Comment: @demux do you want to move `<p>Given` and `&#39;s` inside span tag?

Comment: @demux what's the final output?

Comment: It's in the question