# Use regular expressions to split a string with html by the h1 tags only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a need to retrieve only the h1 tags out of a string that I'm getting via ajax. The string returns the entire page of a php file that uses `file_get_contents` to display a foreign page.

I get the string back perfectly and I want to split the string by the h1 tags. Is there a way to return an array of only the `<h1>` tags? I'm using a filter I wrote based on underscore.js but it doesn't really work:

```
var h1 = toolbelt.filter(textArr, function(element){
        return element.search('<h1') !== -1;
      });
```

this does bring back an array of all of the `<h1>` tags, but only the tags, I would like to get back an array of all of the h1 tags along with the content example output:

`['<h1>sample text here</h1>','<h1 id="someId">Some ID here in h1</h1>]`

I need to be able to do this with pure vanilla javascript as it is for a school project that doesn't allow the use of libraries other than underscore.js.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21870431/4475267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var test = '<h1>hi</h1>more content<div>content div</div><h1>bye</h1>';
var h1Elements = new Array();
$.each(test.split('<h1>'), function(i, content) {
  if (content.indexOf('</h1>') !== -1) {   
  h1Elements.push('<h1>' + content.substring(0, content.indexOf('</h1>')) + '</h1>');
  }
});
console.log(h1Elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I need to be able to do this with either pure vanila javascript or with each, map, reduce filter or reject from underscore.js

Answer (score 4):

Using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
var someHTML = '<div><h1>First</h1></div><h1>Second</h1>';

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(someHTML, 'text/html');

var output = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    doc.querySelectorAll('h1')
).map(el => el.outerHTML);

console.log(output); // ["<h1>First</h1>", "<h1>Second</h1>"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based EXACTLY on [@JorgeHess answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557714/5583283) here is the pure JS version

```js
var html = '<h1>hi</h1>more content<div>content div</div><h1>bye</h1>';
var h1Elements = new Array();

var htmlSplit = html.split('<h1>')

for(index in htmlSplit) {

  if (htmlSplit[index].indexOf('</h1>') !== -1) {   
    
    h1Elements.push(
      '<h1>' + htmlSplit[index].substring(0, htmlSplit[index].indexOf('</h1>')) + '</h1>');
  }
}

console.log(h1Elements);
```