# Html page tags count using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I want to parse an entire html page using javascript and count the total number of different tags present in it using regEx and then print it. Can anyone please help on how I go about doing it? Code will be utmost welcome

For example if this is the html page:

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <a>This is a tagt 2</a> <p>This is 
paragraph1</p> <a>This is Assigntment 2</a> <p>This is paragraph1
</p> <div> <img> </img> </div> <body> </html>
```

Then expected output is:

- Number of `a` tag = 2
- Number of `p` tag = 2
- etc

Comment: You only want to get count of each type of tag ?

Comment: Maybe this will help get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Comment: yes :) like for example if this is the html page <html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
    <a>This is a tagt 2</a>
    <p>This is paragraph1</p>
    <a>This is Assigntment 2</a>
    <p>This is paragraph1</p>
    <div>
  <img>
  </img>
    </div>
    
 <body>

</html> 


then expected output is:
Number of a tag:2
Number of p tag:2
etc

Comment: Yeah, you could use the getElementsByTagName function like so: https://jsfiddle.net/txwf1gs6/

Comment: yaa but in generic context i would not know which tags exists in the html page and also regEx was needed so......

Answer (score 4):

## Description

Count all the tag names in string while avoiding difficult edge cases.

## Example

**Regular Expression**

```
<([a-z]+)(?=[\s>])(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?\/?>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**

- Regular Expression: https://regex101.com/r/mA4hF0/1
- Javascript: https://repl.it/C0gY/1

**Sample Code**

```javascript
var string = "<html> <head> </head> <body> <a>This is a tagt 2</a> <p>This is paragraph1</p> <a>This is Assigntment 2</a> <p>This is paragraph1</p> <div> <img> </img> </div> <body> </html>";

console.log(string);
var re = /<([a-z]+)(?=[\s>])(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*\s?\/?>/gi;
var m;
var HashTable = {};

do {
    // conduct the match 
    m = re.exec(string);

    // verify the match was successful
    if (m) {
        // verify the HashTable has an entry for the found tag name
        if ( !(m[1] in HashTable) ) {
            // no entry was found so we'll add the entry for this tag name and count it as zero
            HashTable[m[1]] = 0
        } // end if

        // increment the tag name counter
        HashTable[m[1]] ++
    } // end if 
} while (m);

console.log("")
// output the number of all found tag names
for (var key in HashTable) {
    console.log(key + "=" + HashTable[key]);
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <a>This is a tagt 2</a> <p>This is paragraph1</p> <a>This is Assigntment 2</a> <p>This is paragraph1</p> <div> <img> </img> </div> <body> </html>

html=1
head=1
body=2
a=2
p=2
div=1
img=1
```