# Regex to count all tags in a string

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to count all the tags inside a string.

Example : [url]some url [/url] some text [img]img[/img]

I have to find here 2 results but i can't

This is my current regex

```
/\[[A-Za-z]([^{]*)[\/A-Za-z]\]/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZscnkO/2/

Thanks everyone for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740880/html-page-tags-count-using-regex

Comment: What do the tags look like?  If they're something known ahead of time, like `<tag>something something</tag>`, then it's doable with regex.  But if you need the whole breadth of valid html, then you'll want to use a parser designed for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZscnkO/3)

assuming the tags your trying to parse don't get any more complex then the ones in your example, then this will do just fine.
`\[(.*?)\].*?\[\/\1\]`

Explanation:
the first part: `\[(.*?)\]` finds the start of a tag and captures it's contents
the second part: `.*?\[\/\1\]` expands the match outwords untill it finds a closing tag with the same contents that were captured from the start tag.