# Download string as html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Form</title>
<body>
<input class="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox  </label>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's assigned to a var, says var html. How do I proceed to download as index.html?

Comment: please elaborate your question...

Comment: This post may help you: Parse a html string with js: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js)