# Is there a library that would help me with formatting data from a html document?

Tags: javascript

Just like in the question. For example I make a request and get a html document with multiple td tags, how to retrieve the data? Do I need to learn regex?

Comment: do you receive document in string format?

Comment: Do you want to read a specific HTML tag information?

Comment: if you want to display the html obtained in the current document, you can append it with jQuery library

Comment: @semanser yes, a string, do you recommend using jQuery like Alfredo EM suggested?

Comment: @youbetternot yes, you can use jQuery. Also you can check this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Comment: thanks guys, you put me on a right path and I've found https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a regex. You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest to get a DOM object, which you can query by the usual methods (CSS selectors, XPath, manual tree walking, etc).

There's also [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) for when you only have an HTML string.