# Parse GET request string as HTML

Tags: javascript, parsing, get

I used a GET request to get the HTML on another page with Javascript and that worked fine but now I need to get a certain class which I could normally do like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

but now I can't do it because it is just normal text. Is there a way I can parse this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a HTML String with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. In this case give us a minimum amount of input and code to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your HTML as a string called `htmlString`, you can create a DOM element and then parse it.

```
var htmlElem = document.createElement("html");
htmlElem.innerHTML = htmlString;

// now perform getElementsByClassName() on htmlElem, not document
htmlElem.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwfuLzkj/)

---

With jQuery, this is even easier. Just use [`$.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/):

```
// $.parseHTML() returns DOM nodes; wrap it in jQuery wrapper to get jQuery object
var htmlElem = $($.parseHTML(htmlString));

// now do what you need
htmlElem.find(".class");
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwfuLzkj/1/)