# How to get an HTML element from a string with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable with HTML in it. All I want to do is extract the last element of the node and click on it using pure vanilla JavaScript.

Here is what I have:

```
var rand = '
 <div class="readmorelink"> 
   <a href="example.com/link-to-follow/">
   Continue Reading        
   </a> 
 </div>';
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: var found = $(rand).filter(".readmorelink");

Comment: I know how to do it jQuery but that needs to be in vanilla JS

Comment: See [Parse a HTML String with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/851811)

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Vanilla JS you can create a DOM element and set its innerHTML to the string you have, it will automatically reproduce the DOM structure inside :

```
// Don't forget to escape newlines
var rand = '<div class="readmorelink">\
    <a href="//example.com/link-to-follow/">Continue Reading</a>\
 </div>';
var elt = document.createElement('body');
elt.innerHTML = rand;
var links = elt.getElementsByTagName('a');
var target = links[links.length - 1];

// Target now equals the last 'a' element in the DOM tree

var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
    "view": window,
    "bubbles": true,
    "cancelable": false
});

target.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Comment: while dispatchevent its redirecting. http://example.com/link-to-follow//example.com/link-to-follow/

Comment: Yes because of the `href` attribute in the `a` element. If that `href` was `//example.com/link-to-follow/` with 2 slashes before (as in the edited post) or with a specified protocol (ie: `https`) it would send you to `example.com` domain