# Javascript [\s\S]* is too greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sample multi line string where in I have to get all the div tags and contents between them where in the p tag is not equal to a specific id

```
var str="<div>
         <p id=\"a\">Sample sentence</p>
         </div>

         <div>
         <p id=\"b\">Sample sentence 2</p>
         </div>"
```

The regex that I was using was too greedy, I only need to match the 2nd div tag and its content but it is also capturing the div tag from above. Here is my regex:

```
<div>[\s\S]*<p id="b">[\s\S]*<\/div>
```

for the regex I used it is capturing the entire string but I just want to capture:

```
<div>
  <p id="b">Sample sentence 2</p>
</div>
```

any regex guru out there that can help me out with this?

Comment: Use a DOM Parser, this is trivial if you are within a browser/node.js, E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js & many other examples here.

Comment: Regexp gurus would advise you not to try to parse/analyze/manipulate DOM with regexp. For instance, it is theoretically impossible to write a regexp which would behave properly in the presence of nested divs.

Comment: Tags are parsable with regular expressions. However, open / close or lack of, and structural relationships between tags is not the forte of regex.

Comment: You can use `[\s\S]*?` to make the quantifier lazy, but this is not a general purpose solution. Use an HTML/XML parser for reliable results.

Comment: 4castle is correct - it's not that your regex is too greedy, it's that your regex needs to be lazy.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://regex101.com/r/awFFyg/1)  can help

Answer (score 1):

As many will advise: [don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839) regular expressions to interpret/parse/extract HTML. Instead use the capabilities of the DOM. For example:

```js
var str=`
<div>
  <p id="a">Sample sentence</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="b">Sample sentence 2</p>
</div>`;

var elem = document.createElement('span');
elem.innerHTML = str;
elem = elem.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)');
console.log(elem.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `/<div>\n.*<p id=\\"b\\">.*\n.*<\/div>/g` if you have to use RegExp in this case. I would however suggest you to use the DOM Parser if you can.

```js
const regex = /<div>\n.*<p id=\\"b\\">.*\n.*<\/div>/g;
const str = `<div>
         <p id=\\"a\\">Sample sentence</p>
         </div>

         <div>
   <p id=\\"b\\">Sample sentence 2</p>
         </div>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```