# Javascript Regex for <IMG> and <A>

Tags: javascript

I have a simply HTML/NodeJS chat that is working well.  User sends a message to a room, the room receives it and displays it on all clients.

However I'd like the user to be a able (as you can everywhere today) paste a URL of a gif/image file and have it displayed in the chat.

Currently I match all hyperlinks with:

`/(https?:\/\/([-\w\-\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w\-\/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/ig`

And on searching I [found this answer](http://(http)?s?:?(%5C/%5C/[%5E%22']*%5C.(?:png%7Cjpg%7Cjpeg%7Cgif%7Cpng%7Csvg))) which will detect image links with:

`(http)?s?:?(\/\/[^"']*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg))`

However I need one to replace hyperlinks and one to replace images and wrap them in `<a>` and `<img src=''`> respectively.

How can I acheive this>?

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML.  Use the DOM to parse the HTML.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Comment: @Amy it's not so much as HTML as a URL, which is fine to parse.  I just can't nail the regex.