# Regex for finding HTML classes with JSOUP

Tags: ios, swift, regex, swiftsoup

For my project I need to parse `HTML` and get the price of a product. This is how I am doing it at the moment:

```
let url = "https://www.adidas.de/adistar-trikot/CV7089.html"
let className = "gl-price__value"

do {
    let html: String = getHTMLfromURL(url: url)
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)

    let price: Elements = try doc.getElementsByClass(className)

    let priceText : String = try price.text()

    result.text = priceText

} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

**Question:**

How can I change `className` to a `regex` so all 3 examples below would match? Ive tried several possibilities now but can not make it work. Happy for every help!

**Example 1:**

```
<div class="price">82 EUR</div>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<span class="gl-price__value">€ 139,95</span>
```

**Example 3:**

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">79,99&nbsp;€</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `getElementsByClass` is not the best way to go. From [SwiftSoup Readme - Use selector syntax to find elements](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup/blob/master/README.md#description-5)

> SwiftSoup elements support a CSS (or jQuery) like selector syntax to find matching elements, that allows very powerful and robust queries.
>
> `[attr~=regex]`: elements with attribute values that match the regular expression; e.g. `img[src~=(?i)\.(png|jpe?g)]`

Your code would became something similar to:

```
let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)

let priceClasses: Elements = try doc.select("[class~=(?i)price]")

for priceClass: Element in priceClasses.array() {
    let priceText : String = try priceClass.text()
    ...
}
...
```

I'm using `price` here as the regex based on the examples you have provided, but you can adapt as you need.

Comment: no idea why your answer or my question is getting downvoted ! I think your answer works, I will test it tomorrow :)

Comment: I have a question about your code. What is **Elements** exactly ? Is it some sort of `array` that holds all the results that were found? Because that's what I would need. Not just one, but all results found. And how would I go though that "array" ?

Comment: @Chris when you call `priceClasses.array()` you get an array of `Elment` objects. On each of those object you can call `ownText()` to get the text within that element. Here is the implementation of that class if you want to see all available methods: https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup/blob/master/Sources/Element.swift

Comment: Good to know about `ownText()` =)

Comment: @Enricoza n1colas.m just edited the answer. Didn't know you can simply call `.array()` . Thanks !

Comment: whats the difference between `ownText()` and `text` though?