# Parse HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string which is inside the HTML code.

here, I need to get a string separately using javascript.

> outsidePara

and

> insidePara

```
var msg="<p><sp id='msgId'>insidePara</sp>outsidePara</p>"
```

Comment: How does NodeJS come into the picture?

Comment: Probably will do what you want:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-a-html-string-with-js

Comment: @AakashVerma here i used nodeJS server to receive JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `<p>` always in the same format (i.e. will always have a ```

If so, jQuery's $('p sp#blablabla') should be able to help as you can then select the text of the parent `<p>` and trim off the `<sp>`

```
var sender = $('p sp#blablabla').text()
var msg = $('p sp#blablabla').parent('p')
var msgHTML = msg.html()
var msgBody = msgHTML.substr(msg.length - (9 + sender.length)); // 9 for the two <sp> tags
```

Comment: <p> always same format, <sp> contains person who send message and out side of <sp>is message.

Comment: what after # i need to do its id or anything

Comment: Yep the text after the `#` is the id of the `<sp>`. This will allow you to select the span element, and you can then use `.parent()` to select the parent `<p>`.

Comment: var detail=$('p sp#YzM',msg);

Answer (score 1):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load(`<p><sp id=\"blablabla\">puppy</sp>hi</p>`)

console.log($("p sp").text()) // will print puppy
console.log($("p").contents().last().text()) // will print hi
```