# How can i find and replace style in specific HTML tag with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

As I mentioned in the title, how can I change the contents of the style attribute within a given HTML tag?

for example:

```
<table class="MsoTableLightShadingAccent1" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-left: 45.9pt; border: none;">
```

I have got many html code like that. I wrote an RegEx like that in js:

```
str = str.replace(/(<(?:table)[^<]*)(style="[^"]*")([^>]*>)/gi,'<table style="font-size:medium;">');
```

this can change table tag but actually i want to delete only "margin-left". How can i do that with js?

Edit: I use summernote. When user paste a text, it triggers onPaste callback and i clean dirty tags and attributes.

Comment: My tip is to use `document.querySelector()` to find your html tag, and then edit it as an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't parse HTML with regex, see this [famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/966798).

JavaScript is perfectly capable of doing what you want though, something like this:

```
<div id="someID" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: red; margin-left: 50px;"></div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('someID').style.marginLeft = 0;">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I understand it but actually i use summernote and when user paste a text to summernote, i want to clean that. So all pasted text goes to my function. So i dont know any id or class in text, i just clean them.

Comment: Can you get the id of the element (a textarea?) that contains the text? Or use a different CSS selector i.e. `#container > div > div > textarea`?

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your edit. So the user pastes HTML as text and you receive the HTML in your `onPaste` callback? You could parse that HTML into a DOM object and then find your element and adjust the CSS? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js][this answer.

Comment: Oh, i see. RegEx becomes a little obsession for me so i couldn't see that solution. Thanks a lot.