# How to execute a POST response content, that is an script tag, automatically in React?

Tags: reactjs, integration

I am working on a react project, that will replace the login page of our legacy system. This react app, however, still need to make a post request to this legacy ASP page because of integration and business rules reasons.

My challenge is to integrate the return of this ASP with react. The legacy response is a string in case of error, or a script html tag in case of success.

**Changing the legacy response is not an option**

Error response example:
`Password/Username is invalid`

Success example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>top.location = 'http://www.contoso.com/myIndexPage.asp?token={FFF6F5F0F-F000-0F00-0000-F000F00F0000}'</script>
```

My problem is how to proper handle the request, and if is a success, execute this script tag automatically? I have tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but it is not executing the script. The script tag is being inserted in the HTML correctly though.

This is how I am using it:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.myASPReturn}} />`

How do I execute the success script tag in case of a valid login, or just show the error message in case of an invalid login?

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution.

First parse the html. I used this technique:  [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js)

```
const string = "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location = 'http://www.contoso.com/myIndexPage.asp?token={FFF6F5F0F-F000-0F00-0000-F000F00F0000}'</script>"

const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = string;
```

Then get the code from the script element and `eval()` it.

```
const scriptString = el.firstChild.innerText;
eval(scriptString);
```

Comment: The response is a script only if it succeed. The error response will be a string, like: `"Invalid user"`. If I eval() this error message I will get an exception.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck you could handle that in a try/catch