# RegEx for matching style tag

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an HTML code that contain CSS code inside  tag under the header tag. I want to use regex to extract all text in HTML, only pure text (between HTML tags ). I tried,

```
console.log(HTML_TEXT.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, ""))
```

which replace every thing between <> by empty char, the problem is the CSS code inside STYLE tag is still there, so i want to know how to write the regular expression to remove CSS code inside  tags.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried .innerText()? That's is what it's for.

Comment: [Obligatory reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579) -- try using DOM methods instead. e.g. [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js)

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/UBnIjo/1) might help you to do so:

```
(\>)(.+)(<\/style>)
```

- It creates a right boundary in a capturing group: `(<\/style>)`
- It has a left boundary in another capturing group: `(\>)`, which you can add additional boundaries to it, if you wish/necessary
- Then, it has a no-boundary middle capturing group, `(.+)`, where your target is located, and you can call it using `$2` and replace it with an empty string, or otherwise.

I'm not so sure, did not test it, but your code might look like something similar to:

```
console.log(HTML_TEXT.replace(/(\>)(.+)(<\/style>)/g, '\\$1\\$3'))
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) explains how to do a string replace in JavaScript.

[image]

Edit:

Based on the comment, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/O17gxU/1) might help you to filter your tags using `$1`:

```
(\<style type=\"text\/css\"\>)([\s\S]*)(\<\/style\>)
```

[image]

Comment: no it doesn't work , my css code contains lines_break ,not only just one ligne ,@Emma

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKfFX.png ) , i tried on my css code , but it does not seem to be working .