# Replacing substrings that aren't substrings of specific tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace key words in the HTML and put a span around them that later will catch a click event.

I get the HTML in string format, and what I tried was to use regular expressions to replace the specific string with the string surrounded by the span. And this all works fine, but the problem is it matches with links and other tags. so it surrounds parts of those too if the key word matches in them.

Code that I used to replace the keywords:

```
textToBeChanged = textToBeChanged.replace(new RegExp(keyword, 'ig'), keywordWrappedInSpan)
```

Is there a way to expand this so that if its in a link or other tag it does not replace it? Or maybe some way with JQuery?

Comment: See the following for some better ways to get started with parsing html, then you can target just text nodes with your replacement, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Comment: You probably should investigate the [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) API.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I don't think I'll be able to use that API the HTML isn't in the DOM. I have to parse it before it gets injected into it. But I was thinking around the same lines. Using JQuery I can parse the string into a JQuery<HTMLElement> or something like that. That has that structure. And I was thinking of traversing it to replace the strings where I need to.  And not replacing it in the child nodes elements where I don't need to.

Comment: please share input string and expected output

Comment: @NagaSaiA if I have for example <div> test <a> test </a> </div> I would like to get  <div> <span>test</span> <a> test </a> </div> where the text "test" wasn't switched out inside of <a> tag

Comment: @LeonCsergity: An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079) to another  SO question suggests a way to use a temporary element to create a document fragment from your string.  You could then walk that DOM.

Comment: @ScottSauyet adding it to the dom isn't the problem. The problem is to modify it the way I need :D

Comment: @LeonCsergity: Well, I was suggesting that walking the DOM would be a lot easier to do than trying to manually parse and alter an HTML string.  But even then, your comment with an example will make this harder than I'd anticipated.  A tree walker makes it easy to visit, say, every text node and make changes, but doesn't keep track of some stack of ancestors nodes; I'm sure it can be managed but not quite as simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below of splitting string by keyword test

1. Split string by word- 'test'
2. Check for characters '' and ''
3. Update span with word test accordingly

working code example

```js
var str = '<div> test <a> test </a> </div>'

console.log(str.split('test').map(v => {
  if(v.indexOf('<a>') === -1 && v.indexOf('</a>') === -1){
    v = v + '<span>test</span>'
  }else{
    if(v.indexOf('<a>') !== -1){
      v = v + 'test'
    }
  }
  return v
}).join(''))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rEvvGV?editors=1010

Comment: Really interesting solution. Sorry for the super late reply though. I could not get around to that part of the application, so only now will I be able to try applying this