# How can I convert anchor elements to React Link components for routing?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I am having problem with handling the `<a>` tag that comes from the backend or database as data. Is there a way to convert them to `<Link>` ? Or is there any other way to route them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to read [ask] and [mcve] for some tips on how to write your question so that we can provide the answer that helps.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit difficult to understand your question. How does your data look when you receive them? Do you receive a string like `"<a href="www.example.com">example</a>"` and insert it into your jsx in render? (like in curly brackets (`{ data.aTag }`)? Please provide some relevant code snippets ("I receive data in this form and I render it in this form") so that we can understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes I recieve data in `<a href="/example">example</a>` form as a string which I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understand what you mean exactly, but this might probably be what you are looking for. Let's say you received your data and it looks like this:

```
let aTag = '<a href="exampleLink">exampleText</a>'
```

To construct your <Link>, all you need is the value for 'href' attribute and the innerText. You can get them with regex:

```
let href = aTag.match(/(?<=href=").+(?=")/g)  // returns "exampleLink"
let inText = aTag.match(/(?<=>).+(?=<)/g)  // returns "exampleText"
```

Then you can construct your <Link>s accordingly and do whatever you want to do with them.

```
<Link to={ href }>{ inText }</Link>
```

---

P.S. The funky looking things in the regex is called 'lookahead' and 'lookbehind':

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookbehind

---

P.S.2. This is not optimal / wouldn't scale well because * the regex for `inText` won't work as intended if your a tag has some more children tags in it; * the regex for `href` may also need some adjusting if your data escapes quotation marks around the href value (i.e., for `href=\"exampleText\"` you'd need `/(?<=href=\").+(?=\")/g`); * you may receive a tags with more attributes (target, rel etc). But if there is a pattern to your data and you know that you will always receive the same pattern, then this might work just fine.

**UPDATE:**

Your further question made me think of a better, much simpler (and also safer) way of doing this. You can basically parse your html string to a dummy html element and then query it later (exactly like explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/7228779)

So you have your data:

```
let data = '<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="/test">dummy text</a> of the printing and typesetting industry.<div>'
```

You create a dummy element and append your data to it:

```
let dummyEl = document.createElement("div");
dummyEl.innerHTML = data;
```

And then get your a tag (or tags) with querySelector:

```
dummyEl.querySelector("a")  // returns the element: <a href="/test">dummy text</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
What if it comes in middle of the content like 
`let data = '<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply <a href="/test">dummy text</a> of the printing and typesetting industry.<div>'`
How do I handle the route of the `<a>` tag in this condition?