# RegEx negative lookahead matches only one character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I wrote a regex that should match all dangerous HTML characters except `<span style="background-color: #any-color">` and `</span>`:

`((?!<span style="background-color: #([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})">|<\/span>)[&<>"'/])`

However, it matches the extra characters that I excluded.
Here RegEx should not match quotation mark `style="background-color:`, but it matches:
[image: incorrect match]

Where did I make a mistake?

See [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ltiwqz/1). Here is the [link to the current project](https://gist.github.com/saber-nyan/fed9fb8057912b0a3254baf9aa14022c):

```
function escapeHtml(in_) {
    return in_.replace(/((?!<span style="background-color: #([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})">|<\/span>)[&<>"'/])/g, s => {
        const entityMap = {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&quot;',
            '\'': '&#39;',
            '/': '&#x2F;',
        };

        return entityMap[s];
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you going to remove those "dangerous HTML characters"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I'm going to escape these characters. I know that after such an operation it is still dangerous to insert them anywhere except the body of the tag, but there I am going to insert the resulting string.

Comment: This is not quite possible in regular text editor without hacks. [This is a PCRE regex solution](https://regex101.com/r/FGCm2j/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm going to use this regex in javascript, something like this: https://gist.github.com/saber-nyan/fed9fb8057912b0a3254baf9aa14022c

Comment: [You should not use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3670132). If you are going to use Javacript, why not use the built-in functions ?

Comment: @Seblor The question is not relevant to HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that you may only use a regex when you have full control of the entities that appear in the plain text string**.

So, if you manually add `</span>` and `<span style="background-color: #aaff11">` like strings you may fix your code like this:

```js
function escapeHtml(in_) {
 return in_.replace(/(<span style="background-color: #(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})">|<\/span>)|[&<>"'\/]/g, ($0,$1) => {
  const entityMap = {
   '&': '&amp;',
   '<': '&lt;',
   '>': '&gt;',
   '"': '&quot;',
   '\'': '&#39;',
   '/': '&#x2F;',
  };
  return $1 ? $1 : entityMap[$0];
 });
}
console.log(escapeHtml('<b>some test <span style="background-color: #333300">ol string!</b></span> nope <i>whoops</i> <span style="background-color: #ff0000">meh</span>'));
```

Else, you need to consider a DOM parsing approach. See [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029).