# How do I get the description and imageUrl inside description tag when parsing an RSS feed using React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rss, rss-reader

This is how an `item` from the RSS feed that Im trying to parse looks like:

```
<item>
<title>
Former cop gets 18 years in prison for shooting civilian to death
</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<a href="https://e.vnexpress.net/news/news/former-cop-gets-18-years-in-prison-for-shooting-civilian-to-death-4020110.html"><img width=130 height=100 src="https://i-english.vnecdn.net/2019/11/30/phuoc146331574997301-157508140-8364-4799-1575086150_180x108.jpg" ></a></br>A Dong Nai court sentenced a former traffic policeman to 18 years in prison on Friday for fatally shooting a man in a family feud.
]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Sat, 30 Nov 2019 12:00:00 +0700</pubDate>
<link>
https://e.vnexpress.net/news/news/former-cop-gets-18-years-in-prison-for-shooting-civilian-to-death-4020110.html
</link>
<guid>
https://e.vnexpress.net/news/news/former-cop-gets-18-years-in-prison-for-shooting-civilian-to-death-4020110.html
</guid>
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

This is how I get the `title` from the RSS feed, I'm using `react-native-rss-parser` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rss-parser):

```
fetch('https://vnexpress.net/rss/tin-moi-nhat.rss')
     .then((response) => response.text())
     .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
     .then((rss) =>  { 
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             ...prevState,

             title0: rss.items[0] ? rss.items[0].title : '',
             caption0: rss.items[0] ? rss.items[0].description : ''
         }))    
     })
```

```
const Feeds = ([
        {
        pic: require('../assets/images/image.jpg'), 
        title: this.state.title0,
        caption: this.state.caption0
      },
])
```

I'm trying to parse the `description` and the `imageUrl` which is nested inside the description tag. How would I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure the parser doesn't do that for you? can you show me the parsed object if possible

Comment: It does, but not how I wanted it. Instead of parsing just the `description` of the `items`. It parses `
19:28
<a href="/* .html url */"><img width=130 height=100 src="/* .jpg url */" ></a></br>Lorem ipsum blah blah`

Comment: I just want it to parse just the `Lorem ipsum blah blah` part

Comment: I believe it's called a ![CDATA[ tag

Comment: yeah i do get what you mean thats because the cdata tag actually but if you are sure that you will always have the text after the tags like the example you mentioned  you can parse it as html using jquery

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can parse it and get all the strings inside if you only need the last string you can get the last index at nodeNames list

```
    str = '<a href="https://e.vnexpress.net/news/news/former-cop-gets-18-years-in-prison-for-shooting-civilian-to-death-4020110.html"><img width=130 height=100 src="https://i-english.vnecdn.net/2019/11/30/phuoc146331574997301-157508140-8364-4799-1575086150_180x108.jpg" ></a></br>A Dong Nai court sentenced a former traffic policeman to 18 years in prison on Friday for fatally shooting a man in a family feud.',
    html = $.parseHTML( str ),
    nodeNames = [];

    // Gather the parsed HTML's node names
    $.each( html, function( i, el ) {
        if(el.nodeName=='#text'){
            nodeNames[ i ] = el.nodeValue;
        }else{
            nodeNames[ i ] = el.innerText;
        }
    });
    console.log(nodeNames);
```

---

with only js this will return text content

```
function parseHTML(html) {
    var t = document.createElement('template');
    t.innerHTML = html;
    return t.content.cloneNode(true).textContent;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using jquery, cause I think I read about this somewhere about how you shouldn't use jquery in React Native (something to do with DOM).

Comment: just edited it the parseHtml function should return text,  credit :https://stackoverflow.com/a/33321421/11252816