# select text inside 2 html tags also the text inside nested tags - RegExp

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I'm fetching all texts inside tags with this expression:

```
/(<\s*(div|a|p|span|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|title)[^>]*>)([^<]+)(<\s*\/\s*(div|a|p|span|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|title)[^>]*>)/gi
```

It's actually fetching but if have statement like this tag inside tag

```html
<p class="lead mb-0">
   Freelance is a free to use, MIT licensed Bootstrap theme created by
   <a href="http://startbootstrap.com">StartBootstrap</a>
</p>
```

it get the text inside the a tag but not the inside p tag also.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. It's a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8967612). But [why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/8967612) Here are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18724992/8967612). Use an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10585029/8967612) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to select the text between the tags, use the following:

```js
(?<=(div|a|p|span|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|title)[^>]*>)([^<]+)/gi
```

The problem with the shared expression is the **expectation of a closing tag** which is not the case for nested tags

```
(<\s*\/\s*(div|a|p|span|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|title)[^>]*>)/gi
```