# DOMParser doesn't parse 'tr' elements as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domparser

I'm trying to parse a string containing some html with `tr` with `DOMParser` but the result is not what I expected:

```
d = new DOMParser()
e = d.parseFromString("<tr><td>hello</td></tr>", "text/html")
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>hello</body>
</html>
```

I expected it to produce a `tr` element in the `body`. What is the issue here?

Comment: `<tr>` is not valid outside of `<table>` so the HTML parser won't parse it. Try `text/xml` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33321421/283366) (link to specific answer)

Comment: Yes it solves the issue