# How to match the spefic fields excludes the contents wrapped in html tags?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large full-text content to handle,which the function is to search the spefic fields,and the results should be high-light.
Here is my way below for example.

```
var content = '<p style="font-size:11px;">This is the content.123</span>'
var keyword = '1';
var Reg = new RegExp(keyword, 'g')
var content = content.replace(keyword, function (match) {
    match = match.replace(Reg, `<span style="color: red;">${keyword}</span>`)
    return match;
})
```

The result I get is like

```
<p style="font-size:<span style="color: red;">1</span>1px;">This is the content.123</span>
```

Obviously not what I want.

So my question is how to match the spefic fields excludes the contents wrapped in  html tags?
And the content may be much more complex than the example i made.

Comment: Parse the HTML, loop through the entire HTML tree and for each node replace the `textContent` only.

Comment: Actually what I get is a string, how to loop through it as a HTML tree?

Comment: You forgot step 1, parse the HTML. Your browser is a HTML parser and has javascript APIs to make this easy. A quick search yields this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Comment: You've just found out this can get complicated fairly quickly. I would suggest using a prebuilt battle tested script for doing it