# Return inner html value of the ajax response html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to return html page throught ajax response, the response return  html codes of the page if I alert. I want to read the inner html of those html codes to get  and  values / contents.
How can I achieve that if ajax request succeed.
Thanks in advance.

// ajax

```
    let req = $.ajax({
        url: '/page',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    });
    req.done(function(response){
        // console.log(response)
        // $(response).find('title').html();
        // $(response).find('.my-header').html();
        alert(response);
    });
```

//html response

```
<head>
    <title>my pagename</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="my-header">HEADER TEXT</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js)

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: I want to read title content returned through response. I have tried // $(response).find('title').html(); but did't work

Comment: @OneBuyu - Try $(response).find('Title').html();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `filter()` instead of `find()`. jQuery  strips out the head of a full page

```
const title = $(response).filter('title').text();
```

Comment: Thank you very muck @charlietfl. I works now.