# Separate string and html tags in a string literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string literal:

`` var str = `Hello<div> This is main content</div>`; ``

I want to insert a `<br>` between "Hello" and the `<div>` tag using `.replace()`.

How can I use `.replace()` on str to add the `<br>` in between these 2 parts?

Thanks in advance.

What I have tried -

```
const breakTag = '<br>';
return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
```

This is not giving the expected results.

Comment: `.replace('Hello<div>', 'Hello<br><div>')`?

Comment: @Cid I've just taken a sample string in my question.
The tags and the string can be dynamic.

Comment: use a proper HTML parser then, RegEx aren't suited to parse html (hint : [JS does it very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js))

Comment: Ob. [Tony the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/438992).

Comment: Your regex seems to suggest that you want to replace all possible line breaks with `<br>`. If that is the case, please reword the question. Currently, your question reads as if you want to insert a `<br>` between the consecutive literals "Hello" and "<div>".

Answer (score 1):

This should get you two groups:

- everything up to the first `<div>`,
- then everything after that.

Then add in the `<br>` and add back in the `<div>`

```js
const breakTag = '<br>';
var str = `Hello<div> This is main content</div>`;
console.log(str.replace(/(.*?)<div>(.*)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '<div>$2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = `Hello<div> This is main content</div>`;
const regex = /Hello/i;
console.log(str.replace(regex, 'Hello</br>'));
```