# How to access a blog-post specific data in theme template?

Tags: html, xml, themes, blogger

I have a blogger site in which I use a custom theme.

I want to give the images which appear in my site homepage an alt and title attribute which I have originally given in the blog post but the theme sets the value of the image alt tag to the post title.
For example in my blogpost I have the following image tag:

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="img-alt" title="img-title">
```

but in the theme data the post image shown in the homepage for the post has these codes:

```
<img expr:src='data:post.featuredImage' expr:alt='data:post.title'>
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
expr:alt='data.post.featuredImage.alt'
```

but it gives no results so how can I access post specific data of tag attributes in blogger theme?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the HTML attributes of the images in the post. Each object has limited and specific properties. You can see the properties of the "data.post.featuredImage" object at this website address:
https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/1971/06/data-posts-featuredImage.html

[data.post.featuredImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrQOb.png)

```
expr:alt='data.post.featuredImage.alt' // [alt] not exist; does not works
```

**IDEA:** Alternative (and expert) solution:
Once the page is loaded, you can manipulate the images with **Javascript**.
You can access the entire post content with the variable `data:post.body`. Add `id` and `data-html` attributes to the image:

```
<img expr:src='data:post.featuredImage' expr:id='&quot;myid-&quot;+data:post.id' expr:data-html='data:post.body' />
```

HTML code to be generated:

```
<img src='img.jpg' id='myid-321' data-html='<!-- post content -->' />
```

Loop all elements starting with `myid-`. Get the `data-html` attribute. [Convert value to DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10585079/8244231). Get `alt` attribute of first image in DOM. Assign this to the `alt` attribute of the image in the loop.